# "The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?

Tags: apt, package-management

I just added a PPA repository for the development version of the GIMP, but I get this error:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
...
The following packages have been kept back:
  gimp gimp-data libgegl-0.0-0 libgimp2.0
```

Why and how can I solve it so that I can use the latest version instead of the one I have now?

Comment: Staggered releases are a safety feature called "[Phased Updates](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421130/39694)."

Comment: @AndrewKoster: or, _tell us why_ it's not, yeah?  That'd be helpful.  Phased Updates does _seem_ to have been the answer for me, though.  See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates ... additionally, `apt show <package>=<new-version>` (where `<package>` is one of the packages listed in `apt list --upgradable` and `<new-version>` is the version string listed as the 2nd (space-separated) field in the output of same) should show a line saying `Phased-Update-Percentage: <n>` for some `<n>` that's the current percentage.  Presumably once that gets to 100%, one will get the upgrade.

Comment: P.S.  I found this helpful (in zsh or bash): `apt show -a $(apt list --upgradable 2>&1 | grep / | cut -d/ -f1) 2>&1 | grep Phased | sort -n | uniq -c` -- shows how many packages are at what phased-update percentages.  (e.g. I currently have 3 at 0%, and 14 at 70%).

Comment: To save everyone a lot of time reading, I recommend looking at Afilu's answer first.

Comment: If everything is working fine in the system regardless of some packages being held back, is it really necessary to "fix" this "warning"? Some will be fixed eventually by doing `apt update` in the long run, and some new others will appear as held back. But if it does not affect the system negatively, would there be a reason to "fix" this excluding getting rid of the warning?

Comment: I wonder what I said here that was so toxic that it got moderated away? LMAO

Comment: @M.K "eventually" may simply not be soon enough for a security update, depending on one's use case.

Answer (score 1957, accepted):

According to [an article on debian-administration.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810160338/https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back),

> If the dependencies have changed on one of the packages you have installed so that a new package must be installed to perform the upgrade then that will be listed as "kept-back".

<sub>(Note that this is not the only reason that you may be seeing the message "packages have been kept back". Another reason is that [phased updates may be enabled](https://askubuntu.com/q/1431940/2355), and the updates have not yet been released for your machine.)</sub>

**Cautious solution 1:**

Per [Pablo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/862799/130), you can run `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade <list of packages kept back>`, and it will install the kept-back packages.

This has the benefit of not marking the kept-back packages as "manually installed," which could force more user intervention down the line (see comments).

If Pablo's solution works for you, please upvote it. If not, please comment what went wrong.

**Cautious solution 2:**

The cautious solution is to run `sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>`. In most cases this will give the kept-back packages what they need to successfully upgrade.

**Aggressive solution:**

A more aggressive solution is to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, which will force the installation of those new dependencies.

But `dist-upgrade` **can be quite dangerous**. [Unlike upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade) it may *remove* packages to resolve complex dependency situations. Unlike you, APT isn't always smart enough to know whether these additions and removals could wreak havoc.

So if you find yourself in a place where the "cautious solution" doesn't work, `dist-upgrade` *may* work... but you're probably better off learning a bit more about APT and resolving the dependency issues "by hand" by installing and removing packages on a case-by-case basis.

Think of it like fixing a car... if you have time and are handy with a wrench, you'll get some peace of mind by reading up and doing the repair yourself. If you're feeling lucky, you can drop your car off with your cousin `dist-upgrade` and hope she knows her stuff.

Comment: As this is an accepted answer needs, it really needs updating to warn about using `dist-upgrade` on a stable system as many of the other answers below have pointed out. Personally I think there is a simpler/safer answer that needs promoted: [apt-get install <list of pkgs>](http://askubuntu.com/a/185402/8570)

Comment: Cas, should I just add that it could be dangerous to run a dist-upgrade on a stable system? Why exactly is that dangerous? (I honestly don't know apt all that well.)

Comment: There is a [Server Fault answer](http://serverfault.com/a/46749/82301) that explains dist-upgrade in a bit more detail. I think its just worth clarifying (not dangerous as such) that it may upgrade the entire system which may be beyond what the user expects/wants i.e. in the OP example they are wondering why gimp is being held back.

Comment: Please note that `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` can also **remove** packages. Consequently, it's best always to inspect the list of changes that will be made before agreeing to them, when running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: I've extended the note warning that dist-upgrade is dangerous. I'm not very satisfied with what I've written. But I want a much more emphatic warning

Comment: i had to use `dist-upgrade` to resume a failed `release-upgrade` the `release-upgrade` failed because of a previously broken package and after fixing that problem the only way to resume the remaining package upgrade was via `dist-upgrade`

Comment: @EliahKagan May I add that even `apt-get upgrade` can remove packages? It will always do that when there would be a version conflict otherwise. Think of `llvm3.6` vs. `llvm3.6v5` (with the "v5" meaning that it was compiled with `gcc 5`). These two __cannot co-exist__, only either of both can be kept on the system. So yes `dist-upgrade` may remove some packages as well, but it's not only `dist-upgrade` that would do this; under certain circumstances, `upgrade` would, as well.

Comment: If you tried `dist-upgrade` and some packages are still "kept back", you can try diagnosing the issue with `sudo apt-get install <package>`; you may find that it is failing because some dependencies are unresolvable (which `dist-upgrade` alone apparently will not tell you)

Comment: The graphical tool that offers you to upgrade your computer software that appears every day there are new software available... does an `apt-get dist-upgrade` every single time. It has nothing to do with upgrading to a new version of the OS (i.e. going from 12.04 to 14.04). It is more a form of distinction between kernel upgrades and other upgrades. In any event, you always want to do a dist-upgrade unless you need to keep running with some old version of software.

Comment: There is less dangerous option, which does not need listing every package manually: `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/what-does-the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-mean

Comment: I just attempted to upgrade from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS. somehow i just got scared that i was lagging behind. so, if we can't upgrade smoothly, i wonder whats the point of keeping our systems. I wonder whether its advizeable tostay on LTS.

Comment: @mac9416, you said "Think of it as upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04". Do you mean this literally? Will `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` change which release of Ubuntu I am using?

Comment: @dinosaur it was a confusing analogy, so I edited it out. `dist-upgrade` does not change the release, because your sources.list files do not change. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade) should help you out.

Comment: `apt-get install` will also mark packages as manually installed, you may not want that. They wont un-install when you remove the package that depends on them.

Comment: @syntaxerror Sorry, I just saw this. What you've described is precisely the situation where one must use `dist-upgrade`. *Running `apt-get upgrade` does not remove packages.* As [the `apt-get` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) says in the description of the `upgrade` action: "Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and installed." So `dist-upgrade` is *categorically* more powerful than `upgrade`.

Comment: FYI, I tried the "cautious" method, apt-get install, and because i'm explicitly teling it to install a certain package, apt feels justified to remove others... You do get a chance to say "no, lets not go that way". 
I got into this mess with an apt-get autoremove that removed a "no longer necessary" package and now two packages are "kept back" and upgrading either will remove 12-15 other packages.  Odd.

Comment: @rew the plot thickens. [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it/602?noredirect=1#comment1618662_185402) agrees apt-get install removes packages. I'm honestly stumped now which is the "safer" solution.

Comment: The first “cautious” option, will also mark packages as manually installed. This may have a detrimental affect when installing another package that depends on them. E.g. You did `apt install games` then one day `pingus` is held back, so you do the fix, then next week you do `apt remove games`. But `pingus` will not be removed, as it was manually installed.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor is there a scenario where that "sticky" package will cause other (truly damaging) package management issues? Or does it just add the inconvenience of having to run an additional `apt remove pingus` to force the removal of that package?

Comment: @mac9416 Probably not. Let me have a go at a scinario. What if it was a library, then it caused you to remove some library by mistake.

Comment: Installing the kept package helped me also with open-vm-tools. Thank you for the solution and explanation.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I feel like that's solved by just keeping an eye on the list of packages to be removed when you manually uninstall (for example) pingus.

Comment: @mac9416 if you want to do the job of apt, then you can do this. However I am not a computer, so I let apt manage my dependencies.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor if you're upgrading "kept-back" packages, you're already dabbling in the role of "human package manager" by altering its default behavior.

Comment: @mac9416 this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/862799/10473 is better. Dabble as little as possible. The argument that I dabbled a little, so I dabble a lot, is not valid. If you are just trying to legitimise your own dabbling, by telling others to do like wise, then please realise that you are legitimate and loved. You can do what ever you want on your own system.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, that does look like a better solution. I'll edit to point folks further down the page.

Comment: I wonder if some of those actions in ubuntu LTS would break the LTS guaranty.

Comment: First solution doesn't work at all, it just does nothing then says again "following packages have been kept back..."

Comment: I think something might have changed about the mechanism, because for me, dist-upgrade actually did nothing and it was the regular install command that asked me to remove the :i386 version of a package. Luckily, apt reports in detail what packages it affects and so I could successfully update the package that was being held back.

Comment: In my case even `dist-upgrade` didn't do anything (at least it didn't do any damage). I had to use **both** "Cautious solution #1" and "Cautious solution #2" in that sequence.

Comment: "Unlike you, APT isn't always smart enough to know whether these additions and removals could wreak havoc." I've been using Ubuntu for 10+ years and I still don't know what 90% of the packages do when I update/upgrade, which is why I rely on the package manger. I have no idea what's using `libsmbclient` or `libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64`  or `bamfdaemon` is doing. I've come to this answer many times and been frustrated by the warning of `dist-upgrade`, which I always considered to be safe.

Comment: @geneorama very fair criticism. 12+ years after writing this answer, I'm so far removed from APT internals that I'm not super confident in what's written there. Unless an APT developer can hop in and make authoritative edits (or someone w/ good references), I'm inclined to leave the answer as-is, especially since the "warn about `dist-upgrade` comment has 208 upvotes. But I share your frustration with the aggressive warning having so little to support it.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw For the records, I appreciate your wonderful answer and follow up comments. Your first suggestion of installing the packages solved my "kept back" issue this time, but I know it hasn't in the past. I've installed R a dozen different ways, and I get this kept back thing often. I've also run dist-upgrade without obvious issue for about 10 years now. I still feel like a Linux Noob and I try to keep my important files in the cloud where they're safe from me.

Comment: `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` works, while `--with-new-pkgs upgrade` does nothing, and the other options are not ideal for other reasons.

Comment: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade is the one giving this message, so that's not a solution. This does not work either udo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade so only installing a package worked

Comment: When `--with-new-pkgs` doesn't works, `apt install --only-upgrade <package_name>` can be a solution and won’t mark the package as manually installed as normal install would.

Comment: On Debian 11 (bullseye), I used the Cautious Solution 1, followed by repeated `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` commands (one of which was a `sudo apt autoremove`) - things went smoothly.

Comment: Isn't dist-upgrade for upgrading your Ubuntu version (not for upgrading software on the current one)?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>` did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: used @GregorySmitherman 's solution: https://superuser.com/a/1263445/244653 for Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: If someone finds this result in 2340, I would like to advise them NOT to force update their airlock controller or fusion reactor services with this technique. Let the phased updates do it carefully.

Comment: Even `dist-upgrade` was not installing the packages for me so I used `install` with the list of skipped packages.

Comment: In the context of a brand-new spun VM, should we go the "unsafe" route to get all the latest release versions, with `dist-upgrade -y`?

Answer (score 687):

Whenever you receive from the command `apt-get upgrade` the message

```
The following packages have been kept back:
```

then to upgrade one or all of the kept-back packages, without doing a distribution upgrade (this is what `dist-upgrade` does, if I remember correctly) is to issue the command:

```
apt-get install <list of packages kept back>
```

this will resolve the kept-back issues and will ask to install additional packages, etc. as was explained by other answers.

**See also**: [Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/a/226213/349837)

Comment: When packages are kept back this way and I manually `apt-get upgrade <list of packages>`, if I redo `apt-get upgrade`, it will list the packages in question as no longer required and that I can use `apt autoremove` to remove them, which I do, and then one last `apt-get upgrade` and they are no longer listed as kept back... Very weird. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does `apt-get install` also remove packages when necessary to resolve gnarly dependency situations, or would you have to run a separate `apt-get remove` command to accomplish that part of the upgrade process?

Comment: @cram2208 I believe that's the expected behaviour. The packages that were "automatically installed and [...] no longer required" are the previous versions of the upgraded packages, which are now no longer needed. `apt autoremove` then removes these unused dependencies.

Comment: If the upgrade would require a new package to be installed, the package will be "kept back."
First consider using: `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` which would _not have side affect of causing packages to be marked as manually installed_

Comment: @mac9416 yes it does.

Comment: @mac9416 see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/818101/21005

Comment: @jarno this leaves me to wonder what the difference between install and dist-upgrade truly is. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @mac9416 `apt-get dist-upgrade` decides which packages it will upgrade and may keep back packages. With `apt-get install`  you have to name those packages expect maybe when using `--fix-broken` option.

Comment: @jarno well that's fair. I meant more in terms of how they handle un-installation of packages. Say you do an apt-get upgrade and packages foo and bar are held back. Previously I'd believed that `apt-get install foo bar` would upgrade the packages, but only if it didn't have to un-install anything to resolve dependencies; whereas `apt-get dist-upgrade` would upgrade the packages, uninstalling anything necessary to resolve dependencies. But now it seems as if they are both willing to un-install things.

Comment: @mac9416 Use `--no-remove` with `apt-get` if you do not want to remove packages.

Comment: I have a strong opinion that it should be possible to force the release upgrade anyway. For example I have installed conky 1.11.3 because in 1.11.4 they introduced reparsing of lua-conky-parse expressions what makes it unusable. It seems they don't want to fix it: https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/967

And I defenetly don't want to upgrade it - I set it to kept back manually.

Comment: This is the only answer that works and doesn't require a full distro upgrade.

Answer (score 458):

I answered a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398989/349837), explaining a bit more about the reasons behind this issue.

---

Try [this Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241062/209677):

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

> This allows new packages to be installed. It will let you know what packages would be installed and prompt you before actually doing the install.

[`apt` command](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.8.en.html) ([friendly alternative](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/) to [`apt-get`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html)) share this option.

**Using `apt install <pkg>` instead will mark pkg as "manually installed"!!** To mark it again as "automatically installed" use [`apt-mark auto <pkg>`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-mark.8.en.html) (see also subcommand `showmanual`). More info [on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831/what-does-it-mean-that-a-package-is-set-to-manually-installed).

Comment: +1 because it does not have side affect of causing packages to be marked as manually installed.

Comment: Note to who ever reads my comment above: not having the side effect of marking as manually installed is a good thing. I like this answer.

Comment: So if you use `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` _without_ running `apt-mark auto <pkg>`, will everything be fine? Is the second command only necessary if you _do_ choose to manually install held-back packages?

Comment: Yes. `apt-mark auto <pkg>` should only be necessary to mark a package as being automatically installed ([here the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-mark.8.en.html)).

Comment: For some reason `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` still shows the packages as "kept back". No error message.

Comment: Just want to add that for many up to date debian 9.6 server instances this was the absolute safest solution without breaking things. Thank you for this, Pablo, as I had luckily tested other options on staging environments beforehand, and could admin many servers up to security standards thanks to the --with-new-pkgs inclusion with much cleaner results for general future package management. Really, this UNIX SE answer should be upvoted!

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw yes, that's the point here. `apt-mark auto <pkg>' is for when you `apt-get install <pkg>` for a pkg that was previously marked auto.

Comment: You can also add the --simulate switch to see what this command would do, without it actually doing it.

Comment: This solution doesn't have the side effect of causing packages to be marked as "manually installed". It also doesn't have the side effect of "actually installing the dang packages".

Comment: This had no effect for me - packages still kept back.

Comment: This doesn't do anything.  Still says `The following packages have been kept back:`

Comment: I think this one doesn't work if a package would have to be removed.

Comment: @endolith and everyone which this didn't work: Please check [my related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398989/349837) and tell us if it helps

Comment: @PabloBianchi I used `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` as in the other answers

Comment: in my case the --with-new doesnt change anything, I get the same have been kept back message. 

But the Hint about make-auto below the main answer part is helpful. 
I already knew excplicit install can help, but also that it will do the manual-installed switch, which is not correct for some kind of dependency library I never installed manually, and this can lead to further problems. So thanks for that hint!

Comment: Warning! Marking packages as "auto" can cause problems if one of the kept-back packages was originally "manual", e.g. "kubuntu-desktop" is normally marked as "manual". If you mark it as auto using this procedure, the next time you do an upgrade it will show many important packages as ready for autoremoval because "they were automatically installed and are no longer required". It may be wise to first check the manual/auto status of the packages and preserve it after the update.

Comment: I found that this answer only works as expected when I pass the package name: `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade <packagename>`

Comment: This answer is not correct. Compare the manual for `apt` with the manual for `apt-get`. In `apt`, `upgrade` says "New packages will be installed if required to satisfy dependencies".  In `apt-get upgrade`, "under no circumstances are [...] packages not already installed retrieved and installed".  The `apt` manual does not document the option `--with-new-pkgs`, because it has no effect on `apt`.

Comment: Using [apt-get --wit-new-pkgs upgrade ....](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt-get.8.en.html#:~:text=APT%3A%3AIgnore%2DHold.-,%2D%2Dwith%2Dnew%2Dpkgs,-Allow%20installing%20new), one SHOULD name the packages that are kept back. When not doing so, nothing happens.

Answer (score 200):

`apt-get dist-upgrade` is dangerous for stable environment,

1. wrong source.list setting and you end up with broken ubuntu.
2. you might get entire application upgraded to version you dont want.

Use case: kernel upgrade kept back, you just want to upgrade the kernel, dont want to upgrade entire distribution.

Better way to handle kept back package:

```
sudo aptitude
```

If you have kept back package you should see Upgradable Packages on top of the list.

- Hit + on that list
- Hit g twice
- Answer debconf stuff if asked
- Press return to continue
- Press Q
- Press yes

Your kept back package installed.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` is only dangerous if you have bad repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`. It's good to be aware that `dist-upgrade` upgrades *all* packages, but with the default repositories, that should be fine. *Not* using `dist-upgrade` could be dangerous, as you might miss security updates.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` can *remove* as well as add packages, but it is not really dangerous. Any package installation command can cause serious damage *if you have problems in your `sources.list` file*! A regular `apt-get upgrade` command will install any package from any software source that is enabled; `dist-upgrade` is not unique in this way. Furthermore, using `aptitude` to perform any operation at all, at least on amd64, is much more dangerous than running `apt-get dist-upgrade`, in a release where [bug 831768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768) isn't fixed.

Comment: For me, it was easier (local machine with X running) to just open synaptic and force the package's upgrade.  For some reason it didn't seem to show up at all where you described in synaptic.

Comment: Also `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`

Comment: @msanford Thank you! Your solution fixed it for me where `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` did not.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will not update/upgrade the whole distribution (like `do-release-upgrade`). It is a misnomer. Use [`full-upgrade` equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/a/770140/349837).

Comment: @msanford Thank you! Your solution also fixed it for me where `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` did not.

Comment: @msanford To go along with that, there's also `sudo aptitude full-upgrade` for when you don't mind it removing packages to upgrade ones that need it.

Answer (score 127):

I'm adding this answer because I'm not satisfied with how other answers handle the **why** part of the question to understand what's going on and choose the appropriate course of action.

Hopefully this will help someone avoid blindly running `apt dist-upgrade` in despair!

## Why is a package kept back?

To my knowledge, there are 3 categories of reasons for packages being kept back during `apt upgrade`.

### 1) It is marked as held back

[`apt-mark`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-mark.8.html) can [do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package):

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package>
```

> hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

To list all packages marked on hold or find out if a package is on hold use:

```
apt-mark showhold
apt-mark showhold <package>
```

To remove a hold on a package and allow it to be upgraded:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package>
```

### 2) `apt` detects a dependency change

The best [authoritative source of information](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-upgrade) I could find regarding this is marked as obsolete, but it says:

> [Kept back] means that there are new versions of these packages which will not be installed for some reason. Possible reasons are broken dependencies (a package on which it depends doesn't have a version available for download) or new dependencies (the package has come to depend on new packages since the last version)

This will tell you the current and candidate upgrade versions of the package:

```
$ apt list <package>

# example output:
vim/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

With the current version (e.g. `2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3`) and new version (e.g. `2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4`), we can figure out the changed dependencies with [`apt show`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-cache.8.html):

```
apt show <package>=<old version> <package>=<new version>

# example:
apt show vim=2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3 vim=2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.4
```

(or just use `apt show -a` to view all versions directly, but it makes the version comparison harder in my opinion)

The important parts are the `Depends` and `Recommends` package lists. If there are new packages in those lists in the new version of the kept back package, apt won't automatically upgrade it.

At this point there are 2 options to upgrade the kept back package. Note that both solutions below have the proper arguments to avoid erroneously changing a package from "automatically installed" to "manually installed".

1. To upgrade the package and install any new "Recommended" packages (i.e. as if newly installed with `apt install <package>`, use [`--with-new-pkgs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html):

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade --with-new-pkgs <package>
   ```

   (Tip: add `--dry-run` to see what will happen before doing it)
2. To upgrade the package *without installing any newly added "Recommended" packages*, use [`--only-upgrade`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-get.8.html).

   ```
   sudo apt install --only-upgrade <package>
   ```

### 3) Phased updates

[PhasedUpdates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates)

> Once an update is released to -updates, the update is then phased so that the update is gradually made available to expanding subsets of Ubuntu users. This process allows us to automatically monitor for regressions and halt the update process if any are found.

You can check for phased updates with:

`sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade --dry-run`

Lots more info here: [What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431940/what-are-phased-updates-and-why-does-ubuntu-use-them)

## Case study: upgrading the `docker-ce` package

Upgrading the `docker-ce` package on Ubuntu 18.04 is what brought me here in the first place so I thought it would be interesting to have a full concrete example.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  docker-ce
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ apt list docker-ce
Listing... Done
docker-ce/bionic 5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic amd64 [upgradable from: 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic]
N: There are 34 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

Ok let's see what's holding back `docker-ce`:

```
$ apt show docker-ce=5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce=5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
Package: docker-ce
Version: 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
Installed-Size: 107 MB
Depends: docker-ce-cli, containerd.io (>= 1.2.2-3), iptables, libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.0), libc6 (>= 2.8), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libsystemd0
Recommends: aufs-tools, ca-certificates, cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite, git, pigz, xz-utils, libltdl7, apparmor
Conflicts: docker (<< 1.5~), docker-engine, docker-engine-cs, docker.io, lxc-docker, lxc-docker-virtual-package
Replaces: docker-engine
Homepage: https://www.docker.com
Download-Size: 22.5 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
Description: Docker: the open-source application container engine
 Docker is a product for you to build, ship and run any application as a
 lightweight container
 .
 Docker containers are both hardware-agnostic and platform-agnostic. This means
 they can run anywhere, from your laptop to the largest cloud compute instance and
 everything in between - and they don't require you to use a particular
 language, framework or packaging system. That makes them great building blocks
 for deploying and scaling web apps, databases, and backend services without
 depending on a particular stack or provider.

Package: docker-ce
Version: 5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
Installed-Size: 121 MB
Depends: containerd.io (>= 1.4.1), docker-ce-cli, iptables, libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.0), libc6 (>= 2.8), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libsystemd0
Recommends: apparmor, ca-certificates, docker-ce-rootless-extras, git, libltdl7, pigz, xz-utils
Suggests: aufs-tools, cgroupfs-mount | cgroup-lite
Conflicts: docker (<< 1.5~), docker-engine, docker-engine-cs, docker.io, lxc-docker, lxc-docker-virtual-package
Replaces: docker-engine
Homepage: https://www.docker.com
Download-Size: 24.8 MB
APT-Sources: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
Description: Docker: the open-source application container engine
 Docker is a product for you to build, ship and run any application as a
 lightweight container
 .
 Docker containers are both hardware-agnostic and platform-agnostic. This means
 they can run anywhere, from your laptop to the largest cloud compute instance and
 everything in between - and they don't require you to use a particular
 language, framework or packaging system. That makes them great building blocks
 for deploying and scaling web apps, databases, and backend services without
 depending on a particular stack or provider.
```

Version `5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic` has added `docker-ce-rootless-extras` as a new recommended dependency. I wish apt would be more helpful and simply suggest installing it or something instead of leaving me with an old version... Anyhow, here are the 2 possible fixes (with `--dry-run` for illustration purposes):

```
$ sudo apt upgrade --with-new-pkgs --dry-run docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst docker-ce [5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic] (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])
Conf docker-ce (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])

$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade --dry-run docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docker-ce-rootless-extras
Recommended packages:
  slirp4netns
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker-ce-rootless-extras
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst docker-ce [5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic] (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])
Inst docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])
Conf docker-ce (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])
Conf docker-ce-rootless-extras (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic Docker CE:bionic [amd64])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is a third reason for kept-back updates: **Phased updates**. These are gradually distributed to increasing portions of the user base until the update is made available to everyone. (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates))

Comment: @Dunkelkoon Correct. When I did the comparison with `apt show` that the answer recommended for one of the packages that are being held back (`gnome-tweaks`), I found that the only differences between the outputs produced for the version I have installed, and that for the available update, were (1) the `Version` line, (2) the `APT-Sources` line, (3) that the installed version had the line `APT-Manual-Installed: yes`, and (4) that the available update had the line `Phased-Update-Percentage: 30`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include PhasedUpdates. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: You can check for phased updates with `sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade --dry-run`.

Comment: Could the mismatch between an installed config file that has been changed on the system versus the one that a new version of an upgradable package wants to install, be another reason for that package upgrade to be held back? I'm thinking of the situation described [here](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/) and that `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade` can resolve.

Comment: @cueedee That's an interesting scenario. I read the article and couldn't find something the results in a package being held back (unless you just don't answer the prompt). It seems like all the `--force-*` options simply allow to skip the prompt you'd get on upgrade, but none of them result in a package being held back. Did I miss something?

Comment: in my case, I just run the command `sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade` (after seeing the effect with the `--dry-run` option) and it simply upgraded the kept back packages. everything is fine in my case.

Comment: @bernie - The situation was an `unattended-upgrades` setup that wouldn't progress completely, and a `base-files` package that was reported to be among those being "kept back".  A manual `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs` entered me into the dialog about two conflicting config files from `base-files` that had been customized locally (`etc/issue{,.net}`).  After that, everything checked out OK again and so I figured that this must have been the reason for keeping back `base-files`.

Comment: Ah I see. If I understand correctly, in that case, since this was an "unattended" procedure, `apt-get` couldn't show a prompt to ask you what it should do, so it refused to upgrade the package.

Comment: @bernie - Yes! Yes Indeed. But would `base-files` _still_ have been listed in the report of "packages having been kept back", if the config-file conflict had _not_ occured, or was the need to show the interactive dialog the only reason for doing so?

Comment: That's a good question, but I don't know the answer :) Something to keep in mind though. I'm happy for you to edit this answer with additional information if you like.

Comment: There's a fourth, albeit this *may* not trigger unless you  run unstable… when package A depends on a *specific* version of package B, and B had an update but A didn't (yet, or it had but it's stuck in the queue).  B is held back, and "forcing" it will then remove A because its dependency will become unsatisfied.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Perhaps I misunderstood, but I have the impression that this is included in `2) apt detects a dependency change`. If you have a suggestion of an extra example to add to that section to illustrate your scenario I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: `apt-mark showhold` returns nothing but `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests onedrive` complaints about `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 onedrive : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.12 is to be installed
            Depends: libphobos2-ldc-shared98 (>= 1:1.28.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 88):

You can also try aptitude. First install it:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude -y
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

It's safer than `full-upgrade` (originally named `dist-upgrade`) because "packages will not be removed unless they are unused".

From [`man aptitude`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html#command-line%20actions):

> **safe-upgrade**
>
> Upgrades installed packages to their most recent version. Installed
> packages will not be removed unless they are unused [...] Packages
> which are not currently installed may be installed to  resolve
> dependencies unless the `--no-new-installs` command-line  option is
> supplied.

Comment: This just gives `sudo: aptitude: command not found`

Comment: @MikeB Did you first install aptitude, as the answer instructed?

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: This worked for me (+1), but I'd like to understand what's happening better. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` did not upgrade the packages for me, so it's not just that it's a safer version of dist-upgrade.

Comment: `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` had also failed for me.

Comment: @Charles If you had the same issue as me, you have to provide the list of kept-back packages after the command (so `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade packageName [packageName...]`. For some reason most of the answers here leave that information out.

Comment: This worked for me after `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` failed. Thank you!

Comment: This is what worked for me. I was following comments in the main question and pointed out to this answer. I guess it would be good to explain why are these two commands solving the issue,thanks!

Answer (score 64):

This has been happening more since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.

The reason is usually [phased updates](https://askubuntu.com/a/1421130/39694). (Thanks to @louis-waweru for the link.)

1. The solution is to ignore those "have been kept back" messages.  When the repository maintainers deem these packages safe enough for you to install, you will get them.
2. If you absolutely must get these updates, you can create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-Phased-Updates` with the contents:

```
Update-Manager::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates "1";
```

Comment: This!  This seems to be the answer relevant to me.  Further note: when I do `apt list --upgradable`, it shows various packages and old and new versions.  I can then do `apt show package -a` on any of the listed packages, and, at least in my case, I'll see something like `Phased-Update-Percentage: 70` or `Phased-Update-Percentage: 0` or whatever.  See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates

Comment: You can also avoid using `apt` and use `aptitude` instead. If you run `sudo aptitude upgrade` or `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade`, it will install all the available upgrades without minding about phased updates.

Answer (score 43):

There are normally two reasons you may see this message.

If upgrading the program (via `sudo apt-get upgrade`) would cause packages to be added or removed, then the program will be held back. You can use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in this case, which will then offer to add or remove the additional packages.

This is pretty common and usually not an issue. Occasionally (particularly during an Ubuntu alpha) a `dist-upgrade` will offer to remove a lot of other programs, in which case you probably want to cancel it.

If the package depends on packages or versions that are not available, then the program will be held back. You really can't do anything but wait in this circumstance, since the package is basically uninstallable. This can happen when packages get added to the repository out of order, when a package is renamed, or when a package stops providing a virtual package.

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether the held package needs a dependency that can't be installed or if it is being held because other packages depend on it. I have many held packages and I believe both of these cases may apply on my system.

Comment: Thanks, the second reason was the issue for me. Even `apt-get dist-upgrade` refused to install it. Inspecting the package with aptitude showed that it depends on a package that isn't available. I guess I'll have to wait.

Answer (score 30):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic and newer Ubuntu versions … provide a *streamlined syntax* via `apt full-upgrade` which functions like `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

```sh
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

> **`sudo apt upgrade`** is used to install available upgrades of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources configured via sources.list(5). New packages will be installed if required to satisfy dependencies, but *existing packages will never be removed. If an upgrade for a package requires the remove of an installed package the upgrade for this package isn't performed.*
>
> **`sudo apt full-upgrade`** performs the function of upgrade but will *remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole*.

Note: `sudo apt full-upgrade` remains on the current distribution.

See: `apt` man page: [18.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html), [20.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html), [22.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/apt.8.html), [22.10](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/apt.8.html)

Comment: After this operation, 2,548 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'

Comment: `full-upgrade` does the same thing as `dist-upgrade`! This answer is wrong! See here https://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Comment: @bernie Answer updated per your observation.

Answer (score 26):

Most likely these packages are held back because their installation would create dependency inconsistencies. This can either happen because you are using archives under active development, ppas, or because the mirror you uses is not fully updated.

In the last case, just wait, when the dependencies are resolved it will be installed the next time.

**Edit:**

There is another possibility, packages might be held back if there is put a hold on them, or if they are pinned.

Comment: What do you base that likelihood on, without knowing whatever he ran an apt-get upgrade or an apt-get dist-upgrade (alt. the aptitude equivalents)?

Comment: this is the most occurring problem in support questions and bugs

Comment: Agreed. You should probably wait and check you apt_preferences. This is often caused by development archives where the and available packages dependencies are changing very quickly. Wait for them to settle down and you may not need to `dist-upgrade` at all. If you'd still like to `dist-upgrade`, then look at the NEW packages to be installed and the packages to be removed before going ahead.

Comment: This is my case because I get the "kept back" message using dist-upgrade

Comment: In cases where this problem is due to a messup with apt preferences (pinning), I found reinstallation of the kept packages helped me: `apt-get install --reinstall <packages>`.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me

```
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

Comment: Even `aptitude upgrade` worked for me.

Comment: I\`am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and I does not have `aptitude` command line

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` gave me the same message, but this solved it for me. I had a package which was breaking the upgrade of another package. I didn't need the one I installed, so `aptitude full-upgrade` gave me the option to remove it so it could upgrade everything else.

Answer (score 14):

This is usually because the package has added a dependency, and upgrade doesn't want to add it for you without permission.

If you run:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-data libgegl-0.0-0 libgimp2.0
```

Then the new versions should be installed together with their new dependency.

Comment: Upgrades specific packages (and their dependencies) without the commitment (risks) of a dist-upgrade.

Comment: The package manager doesn't want to manage packages "without my permission" even though I manually typed `sudo apt upgrade`. Lol.

Answer (score 9):

I have found that aptitude does a better job at upgrading packages if the versions differ just slightly. I had a situation like this:

```
me@compy:/etc/apt$ apt-cache policy gzip
gzip:
  Installed: 1.3.5-15
  Candidate: 1.3.5-15+etch1
  Version table:
     1.3.5-15+etch1 0
        500 http://archive.debian.org etch/main Packages
 *** 1.3.5-15 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This made apt-get hold back the update, but aptitude updated it just fine. I'm unsure which algorithm is used to determine if a package should be updated or not. I guess these two had the same version, only a different 'qualifier'. But in any case, apt-get wouldn't update it, but aptitude would.

Answer (score 8):

[Update/Upgrade not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421222/update-upgrade-not-working)
[last answer]

The kept-back packages (...) are currently in Phased Updates.

```
Phased Updates is one precaution to prevent everybody from receiving a buggy package via upgrade: Some people get the upgraded a few days earlier, others a few days later. This provides an opportunity to pause distribution if early folks report problems.
```

There is nothing wrong. Your system is NOT broken.

Comment: I don't know yet if this is the ***correct answer***, but I do know that the *highly-upvoted answers* here are ***incorrect answers*** - unless perhaps you're running a 10-year-old-system.

Comment: For what it's worth, this _seems_ to be what I'm running up against.  More info at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates ... I wish apt would mention this in the "kept back" messaging!

Comment: @Seamus the question is from 2010, so no wonders they answers are mostly not correct if the behaviour changed in the OS version released in 2022. Seems there's a new mechanism which this answer is valid for and seems like the mechanism is quite good to avoid unnecessary harm. As lndes noted, it would be good if apt mentioned something about this new mechanism.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like the correct way to reinstall kept back package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libjpeg-progs
```

At least this worked for me when `libjpeg-progs` was stuck after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.  I'm sure you can do the same with any other kept back app, e.g. `gimp`.

[Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321702&p=13476183#post13476183)

Comment: You could do it without `--reinstall`, too.

Comment: Funny thing is that it removes the libjpeg-turbo-progs package.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem when a new kernel was released. (Possibly because I have unstable updates enabled.) I found the simplest way to do the install was through Ubuntu's graphical installer (`update-manager`).

Answer (score 5):

In my case packages held back were those related to *linux-headers* and kernel. I came to this by trying to solve an issue with having a red exclamation mark in the notification area and not being able to update packages.

To solve it, I did not have to use neither *dist-upgrade* nor manual *apt-get install xxx*.

What I did and has helped has been **simple and clean**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I had to manually confirm Grub update and its configuration.

Then I just worked with the computer for a while and then standard update dialogue has appeared again finally including "Ubuntu base" section with kernel and related. The update was performed without any trouble and I do not see any held back packages any more.

Also, it is very important to keep in mind that those *buntu updates including **kernel updates are sensitive to hibernation** - I've got this problem several times and I always get it resolved by restarting the machine and performing the steps above.

So maybe this would be just enough?!

(situation being described in here is related to my Xubuntu 15.10 in the end of december 2015)

Answer (score 5):

While other answers have cautioned that `apt dist-upgrade` might remove programs, **notice that you can just run the command and then answer "no" to the "Do you want to continue?" question in order to investigate what apt would do**.

---

After updating a raspberry pi from buster to bullseye I ended up with apt reporting

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  sshfs
```

So I started searching for the error message, landed on this page, read a few answers and then ran

```
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse3 libfuse3-3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  sshfs
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 147 kB of archives.
After this operation, 196 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

At this point it is clear that `fuse` had been replaced by `fuse3` and I am happy to let apt remove it.

---

Your situation might be different but doing a (potential) dry-run will give you more detailed information and quite possibly answer the "why" question.

Answer (score 4):

In actual fact, the switch you need is `dselect-upgrade` which installs / removes dependencies for the particular package set involved.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem using synaptic because it appeared to hang, and to try and fix this I re-booted and tried again.

**SOLUTION:** Then I discovered an informative message as part of the package with some post-installation instructions for me.

I had to hit "**details**", and then '**q**' for quit after reading the message, and then things proceeded normally.

Answer (score 3):

I have read all the posts and found that there are many interesting explanations. I was trying all of them but have not any results completely.
I have a problem with **mysql-utilities** which I couldn't upgrade. The updating was proposed by the system.
 So, I want to show some steps to do it. Of course, I will repeat in some moments all of the aforementioned posts. Here is my mistake, yes I found it by already existed posts, but what should I do next?
[image]

The next step is:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-utilities
```

The results we can see in the image beneath. I remove the package and check this by command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Results - Fine!
Later I installed this new version of package correctly.
[image]

This way, I think can help for more new people because having other packages we can do the same steps.

Once, I am sorry, when I repeated in some places other posts.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal text, since that makes it unsearchable by Google and unreadable by some people. Instead, paste the terminal text into your answer, select that text, and press the `{}` button in the editor to properly format it.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Thanks for remarks, I will take it in opinion for the future.

Answer (score 3):

For me and several commenters on Pablo's answer,

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade  # No effect
```

had no effect. I do not care to have my package marked as manually installed, so I did the following, using kept back package `docker-ce` as an example:

```
sudo apt install docker-ce  # Answer no, do not install
```

Abort the installation by answering `n`. Observe the new package(s) that would have been installed, and install them:

```
sudo apt install docker-ce-rootless-extras
```

Now `apt upgrade` will upgrade the previously kept back package:

```
sudo apt upgrade  # Upgrades docker-ce
```

Answer (score 2):

This one line solves the issue automatically for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade `sudo apt-get upgrade | awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} /The following packages have been kept back:/ { flag=1} /^ /{if (flag) print}'`
```

It runs minimal update with --only-upgrade flag so it should not add any unnecessary packages to the dependency.

How: the line above looks for the "The following packages have been kept back" message in `apt update` and if found' it feeds the list to `apt-get install --only-upgrade`

**Note**: be very careful with  any modifications to your system. Doing things with apt may leave your system broken!

I always run `apt update a&& apt upgrade` just to make sure the upgrade is stable.

Answer (score 1):

I always run dist-upgrade on my dev laptop because I like latest and greatest, it is not do-release-upgrade which actually upgrades to a newer version,

On ubuntu 22.04 I had this issue with both :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-inspiron-5482:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-inspiron-5482:~$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

So both solutions from the highest rated answer do not work.
What worked is to install a package, it actually had the other two as dependencies:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

After that the 3 packages installed and everything is up to date.
I wonder why those were kept back, I seen no difference on my system, but perhaps there is an issue with the new release running the tools.

Anyway, this is the only option that works for me.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat

Comment: Regarding what FedKad said (22.04 LTS on WSL2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiSFp.png

Answer (score 1):

Some recently installed packages may require a reboot before new can be installed (and the latter are held back), e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
distro-info-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.52ubuntu0.2 all [upgradable from: 0.52ubuntu0.1]
gnome-shell-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 42.5-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gnome-shell/jammy-updates 42.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.06-2ubuntu7]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.180+2.06-2ubuntu7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  clang-9 cpp g++ gcc gcc-10-base kali-linux-default lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 libatomic1 libcc1-0
  libclang-common-9-dev libclang-cpp9 libgcc-s1 libgfortran5 libgomp1 libitm1 libllvm9 liblsan0 libobjc4
  libpython2-stdlib libquadmath0 libstdc++6 libtsan0 libubsan1 linux-headers-amd64 llvm-9 llvm-9-dev llvm-9-runtime
  llvm-9-tools python2 python2-minimal python3-chardet python3-pandas python3-pandas-lib
```

apt upgrade; apt update just kept coming back to that and wouldn't install anything. There was a huge block of stuff as well that needed to be autoremoved and that went fine, but still would not install the kept back packages. I tried the easy options 1 and 2 way up there at the beginning of this thread and they did not work.

So I just did apt install /that whole list of kept back packages/, and it all started going.

I've actually never run into this problem before. I just thought it was odd that apt update; apt upgrade didn't work but apt install and then copying that whole list in went off without a hitch and it's working fine now.

And I'm going to apologize now. I wasn't using an ubuntu distribution (I just realized this). I was actually updating a Kali installation when this all occurred. I've never seen anything like this on Ubuntu.

Let me know if I should delete this post (still new).

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Following a `do-release-upgrade`, your third-party or private repositories (such as PPAs) may be disabled. This can stop a package being updated because it can no longer find the dependencies it needs, and/or old packages conflict with newer packages.

Have a look through your `.list` files, usually in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, to see what needs to be re-enabled.

Then run `apt update` and try again.

This is happened to me after a `do-release-upgrade` on a Google VM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the message because I run `sudo apt upgrade` without first running `sudo apt update`.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  alsa-ucm-conf fonts-opensymbol libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress
  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary
  libreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-uiconfig-calc libreoffice-uiconfig-common libreoffice-uiconfig-draw
  libreoffice-uiconfig-impress libreoffice-uiconfig-math libreoffice-uiconfig-writer libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 python3-uno uno-libs-private ure
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
```

Running `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade alsa-ucm-conf fonts-opensymbol libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-drawlibreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impresslibreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementarylibreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-uiconfig-calc libreoffice-uiconfig-common libreoffice-uiconfig-drawlibreoffice-uiconfig-impress libreoffice-uiconfig-math libreoffice-uiconfig-writer libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 python3-uno uno-libs-private ure` as suggested in other answers did not help.

```
$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade alsa-ucm-conf fonts-opensymbol libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-drawlibreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impresslibreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementarylibreoffice-style-yaru libreoffice-uiconfig-calc libreoffice-uiconfig-common libreoffice-uiconfig-drawlibreoffice-uiconfig-impress libreoffice-uiconfig-math libreoffice-uiconfig-writer libreoffice-writer libuno-cppu3libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 python3-uno uno-libs-private ure
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice-drawlibreoffice-gnome
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice-impresslibreoffice-l10n-en-gb
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice-style-elementarylibreoffice-style-yaru
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice-uiconfig-drawlibreoffice-uiconfig-impress
E: Unable to locate package libuno-cppu3libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3
```

I ran `sudo apt update` before `sudo apt upgrade` and it worked out.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease                                                                      
Get:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 Packages [331 kB]
Get:7 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main i386 Packages [168 kB]
Get:8 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [296 kB]
Get:9 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/universe i386 Packages [123 kB]
Fetched 1,027 kB in 1s (792 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
34 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Answer (score -1):

For the very specific flavour of this problem where the proprietary nvidia drivers are halfway updated to a new version, I reinstalled them using the driver manager. To give some context: I was stuck halfway between the 440 and 450 version of the driver and a whole package of libnvidia 440 packages were kept back. This resulted in my kubuntu being stuck at the spash screen after grub. To get into the system, I had to add "nomodeset" to the grub command as described [here](https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/).

In this specific case

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

did have no effect. However, I was able to reinstall the drivers through the additional driver management. In my case, on Kubuntu I started

```
sudo kubuntu-driver-manager
```

On Ubuntu you can reach the same thing via System Settings > System > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers

There I selected the 450 driver and the graphic drivers were reinstalled, resulting in a properly booting machine.