# How to uninstall Haguichi/Hamachi completely?

Tags: package-management, software-uninstall

I want to completely uninstall Haguichi and Hamachi from my computer.

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Uninstalling Haguichi (a graphical frontend for Hamachi)

Assuming you installed [Haguchi](http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Haguichi-a-graphical-frontend-for-Hamachi-on-Linux-that/td-p/40716) through the [Webupd8 Haguchi PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/haguichi) as recommended on [the Haguchi download page](http://www.haguichi.net/download/), you can uninstall the `haguichi` and `haguichi-appindicator` packages and remove the PPA from your software sources.

I suggest using the [`ppa-purge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) utility to accomplish this. If you don't have it, install the [ppa-purge [image: Install ppa-purge]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ppa-purge) package first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then use it to remove the Haguchi PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/haguichi
```

#### Uninstalling Hamachi

Assuming you installed Hamachi with one of the `.deb` files provided at the [Hamachi for Linux download page](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux), just remove the `logmein-hamachi` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove logmein-hamachi
```

That stops the Hamachi service and uninstalls Hamachi. If you want to also remove systemwide configuration files, you can use `sudo apt-get purge logmein-hamachi` instead.

#### Removing `lsb-core`

Optionally, you may wish to remove the `lsb-core` package (and any of its dependencies that are not required by other software you've installed). On Ubuntu this package is not very commonly installed, but `logmein-hamachi` depends on it, so you probably installed it when you installed Hamachi originally.

Just in case something else is depending on `lsb-core`, I recommend [marking it as automatically installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/840/22949) and then performing autoremoval of unneeded packages, rather than forcing it to be removed:

```
sudo apt-mark auto lsb-core
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If you want to also remove systemwide configuration files, you can use `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` instead of `sudo apt-get --autoremove`.