# Installing build essential after gcc

Tags: apt, software-installation

Does it make any difference (dependencies/installed software etc.) when `gcc` was installed before build-essential?

To be more specific, is it any difference between:

```
apt install gcc
apt install build-essential
```

AND

```
apt install build-essential
```

Comment: `build-essential` includes as a dependancy, `gcc` so the second  version of commands will install gcc as part of installing `build-essential`.  In short, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of `gcc` and `build-essential` from the Ubuntu repositories, there is only one difference: Explicitly installing `gcc` (via `apt install gcc` or `apt install gcc build-essential`) marks it as manually installed. This means that using `apt autoremove` after uninstalling `build-essential` (and any other packages depending on `gcc`) will not remove `gcc` or any of its dependencies.

In the general case, nothing more can be definitely said about installing a dependency X first and then the dependent package Y. It's possible that X is one of many fulfilling the particular dependency, and installing Y directly could have caused another package to be installed instead of X.

See also:

- [What does it mean that a package is "set to manually installed?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/831/158442)