# What does the presence and absence of "automatic" mean in apt output?

Tags: apt, aptitude

In the below output, what does `automatic` mean?

```
$apt search exfat
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
exfat-fuse/focal,now 1.3.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  read and write exFAT driver for FUSE

exfat-utils/focal,now 1.3.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  utilities to create, check, label and dump exFAT filesystem
```

And in this context are there any similar/other output details to be known about `apt` (and the `apt` family tools) output?  Any refs will be great.

### Edit 1:

In place of `automatic`, what other values are possible? I have searched:

```
apt  -qq list | grep installed | grep -v automatic
apt-file/focal,focal,now 3.2.2 all [installed]
aptitude/focal,now 0.8.12-1ubuntu4 amd64 [installed]
base-passwd/focal,now 3.5.47 amd64 [installed]
console-setup/focal,focal,now 1.194ubuntu3 all [installed]
dash/focal,now 0.5.10.2-6 amd64 [installed]
diffutils/focal,now 1:3.7-3 amd64 [installed]
```

I don't see anything like `manual` as suggested in the comments. Both `apt-file` and `aptitude` were installed manually by me, so shouldn't there be a `manual` tag for these packages?

### Edit 2:

To clarify completely. There is no tag called `manual`. So it's implicit: if it's not `automatic` then it has to be inferred as `manual`.

Comment: It has something to do with packages that are installed as dependencies or from a metapackage, more here: [What does it mean that a package is "set to manually installed?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831/what-does-it-mean-that-a-package-is-set-to-manually-installed)

Comment: _“I don't see anything like manual as suggested in Q's is comments.”_ Well, it’s implicit, i.e. simply manual = not automatic (nothing shown after `installed`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic means it was installed as a dependency of another package.  If a package is installed as "automatic" and you specifically need to install it, you should still do a "apt install " which marks it as manual.  Automatic packages can be cleared out by "apt autoremove" should the parent package be removed.

Comment: That answers.. I will test

Comment: tested it - there is no tag `manual`. So it's implicit - if it' not `automatic` then it has to be inferred as `manual`.