# Apt-get packages "kept back"

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The following packages have been kept back:” Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would really like to be able to update my install again.

By the way I ran the sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade command

[image: apt get screenshot]

Comment: Don't post a screenshot, copy-paste from the terminal! A screenshot is not searchable. And your screenshot is missing the beginning, copy-paste everything from the command you ran.

Comment: Try and do a dist-upgrade. 
Usually the packages are held back if the upgrades implies system changes.

Comment: @MariusBalaban that worked, if you want credit for the answer respond in that manor and I will approve it

Comment: it's good enough if you understood what was happening.