# Installing Programms Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

In my ubuntu 14.04, I can not download any program from ubuntu software center - it returns this error message:

```
Not Found. There isn’t a software package called 'name of the program' in your current software sources.
```

When I try to install something using ubuntu terminal - it returns this message:

```
Package fglrx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fglrx' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to change the server and nothing happened.

When I make `sudo apt-get upgrade` it shows:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
libdbus-1-3:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libudev1:i386 libuuid1:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded."
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- sudo apt-get clean all
- sudo apt-get autoremove
- sudo apt-get update

Comment: Hi ! When i make sudo apt-get autoremove it returns this message
"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded."

When I make sudo apt-get update it returns me this message:

"W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/munin-plugins/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

Thank's for the answer.