# 14.04 server update without upgradeing to 14.10

Tags: server, upgrade, updates

I have a server running ubuntu 14.04 trusty. When i ran a `sudo apt-get upgrade` today it reported that it will keep back

```
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-headers-server linux-image-generic linux-image-server linux-server
```

I know that i can upgrade these packages by running a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but my question is wheter this will lead to my server being upgraded to 14.10 because I definately want to stay on 14.04 no matter what.

Furthermore could a `dist-upgrade` of these packages result in compatibility problems? When I start a dist-upgrade I get the following output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
    linux-headers-3.13.0-39 linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
    linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
    linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-headers-server linux-image-generic
    linux-image-server linux-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from "man apt-get":

***dist-upgrade***

*dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; **apt-get** has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may therefore remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package files. See also **apt_preferences**(5) for a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual packages.*

So no, you won't upgrade to 14.10 by using it.

OTOH, from my experience, most times when packages are kept back like that the reason is that their dependencies are not (yet) available in the repository. So if you wait a few hours, you should be able to upgrade using the ususal `apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with `apt-get install` `{list of held back packages}`, that worked for me several times.

"dist-upgrade will install all pending updates, with their new dependencies. If for some reason, you don't want to do that, you should use apt-get install package-name dependency-package-name instead."

["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)