# The following packages have been kept back

Tags: upgrade, held-packages

I have already tried all the usual fixes to this .. no luck so far

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libhwloc-plugins
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

none of the following help

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just copy the package names that have been kept back and add them on a `apt-get install` statement.

```
sudo apt-get install package-names
```

Your case will be:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386 libhwloc-plugins
```

Comment: I had to just remove both and it cleared it up - thanks

Comment: To get a little insight into the package you can use `apt-cache policy {packagename}`

Comment: As is mentioned in the [linked question](http://askubuntu.com/a/602/325210), `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is the best solution, its not a good idea to `apt-get install` the packages.

Comment: Actually the linked question state "`dist-upgrade` can be quite dangerous".