# apt-get upgrade: why is lxc-docker being kept back?

Tags: upgrade, updates, docker

Why is lxc-docker being held back? I also notice that my web app, running on Docker, is quite slow. Any suggestions?

```
[lucas@production]/home/lucas$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  lxc-docker
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
[lucas@production]/home/lucas$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  lxc-docker
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Note that I have already run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, which does not resolve this issue. Thus, I don't think my questions is a duplicate of [this questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Comment: Whats the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep "hold"`?

Comment: @heemayl There is no output, which I think means that I have not manually placed a hold on the `lxc-docker` package. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Wow, that did it! I should have thought of that. `apt-get install lxc-docker` ended up removing `lxc-docker-1.4.1` and installing `lxc-docker-1.5.0`. It's rather odd that this wasn't included in the upgrade or dist-upgrade. Feel free to post an answer and I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can upgrade `lxc-docker` specifically:

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

That should override whatever holds back the upgrade (barring manually held packages, which we excluded in this case).

Comment: There's [one answer exactly like this one](/a/185402/175814) to the question, of which this question is flagged as a duplicate.