# How to re-install libgcc1:i386 which breaks libgcc1?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, aptitude, multiarch

So, I went and did something very stupid. I have ubuntu-toolchain-r repository added to repositories which has up to some time ago provided libgcc1:i386 among other things. For a some time now the i386 packages have been shown as kept back during upgrades. I've ignored those since they are rather vital libraries but today I decided to look into it a bit.

I stumbled upon this ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) and went to use the aptitude gui approach without realizing that it shall do basically the same thing as `apt-get dist upgrade` and as the gui hanged for a while, it took in my key presses after a while without me having a chance to do anything before it started to do some horrid package removing to my misfortune. I went and killed the aptitude process but a lot of damage was already done.

So afterwards killing aptitude I carefully went through the list of packages that it had removed and re-installed those. All except the ones that need ia32-libs or libc6:i386, meaning for example my wine and lots of other 32-bit applications and packages that I use because it all comes down to the fact that I can't re-install libgcc1:i386 package since it breaks libgcc1 package and vice versa (same goes for libstdc++6).

```
ahti@ahti:~$ sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1 : Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04) but 1:5-20150401-0ubuntu12~12.04 is to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc1 (!= 1:5-20150401-0ubuntu12~12.04) but 1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

So previously libgcc1:i386 was kept back in my system not causing any problems. Now that it's not there anymore and can't be re-installed it's bringing me a lot of things I can't re-install or use.

Here are results for `apt-cache policy` command:

```
ahti@ahti:~$ apt-cache policy libgcc1
libgcc1:
  Installed: 1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04
  Candidate: 1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
ahti@ahti:~$ apt-cache policy libgcc1:i386
libgcc1:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:5-20150401-0ubuntu12~12.04
  Version table:
     1:5-20150401-0ubuntu12~12.04 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

Also I do have `foreign-architecture i386` in my `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` and [here](http://pastebin.com/Ebch90fr)'s a result of `aptitude install wine` command.

Is there anything I can do? This was a classic case of "if it ain't broken, don't fix it". Please help?

My system is 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.5 with 3.2.0-80-generic kernel and `gnome-session-fallback`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the libgcc1 package that is requested?

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386=1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04
```

or pin it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -e 'Package: libgcc1:i386\nPin: version 1:4.9.2*\nPin-Priority: 500'  > /etc/apt/preferences.d/multiarch-libgcc1"
```

Comment: The first command gave me this:
ahti@ahti:~$ sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386=1:4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
E: I wasn't able to locate a file for the libgcc1 package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.