# 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates

when i update and upgrade , i show these lines
 The following packages have been kept back:
   mysql-utilities
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

but when i use dist-upgrade then i show these lines

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for anki: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for anki: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-utilities
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

unable to upgrade

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: There is nothing to upgrade. All upgrades are installed. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: i used all these but when i am trying to upgrade then i again show the line     0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded

Comment: After trying Pilot6 suggested commands again try `sudo apt-get upgrade` and post the error as it is in your question please!

Comment: i post the output of sudo apt-get upgrade @Ravan

Answer (score 30):

First step always before updating or installing something is to run `sudo apt-get update`

Second step is to run your `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

One final point, if there's nothing to upgrade, then it won't upgrade anything.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If he's not running the preliminary commands, or if there's nothing to do, then nothing will be done.

Comment: Therefore there's no real issue.  He's just got the latest versions of everything.

Comment: The question was why `1 not upgraded` is still there after `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: This question may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Comment: It's got a good answer for why things might be kept back, IMHO.

Comment: @Daniel sir i always follow your method for update and upgrade

Comment: Yes, Thank you Dan, while we -promptly- skip over the text - in this box: 'Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"', heh.

Anyway, this 'issue' is always *the question* with all n00b users, I mean, hehe; AND, yes, please leave alone teh '_ not upgraded' portion to avoid wrecking havoc! :) 

... There is USUALLY no need to force it, as it'll most probably *not* be a security, critical, issue & it could eventually get sorted - as the software versions (those, direct, dependencies) move along - right?? :)) Cool!! :)

Comment: @Nostromov, If there is a package being held back, it can cause a chain reaction resulting in many other packages being held back because they depend on that first package (which has been held back).  I had this issue on one of my servers.  After the chain reaction finished, I was left with 129 packages being held back, including PHP5 and MYSQL, two very important things for a webserver.

Comment: When in doubt, fix it.  Because it is broke.