# How do I completely remove Steam or .deb file?

Tags: uninstall, steam

I would like to know how to uninstall Steam. I looked everywhere but I cannot find any answers. I think it is worth mentioning that I installed it from a website and not the Software Store.

Comment: If you installed directly from the Ubuntu repositories or from the .deb file you can uninstall it with the Ubuntu Software tool.

Comment: I downloaded it directly from the Steam website.

Comment: https://store.steampowered.com/about/

Comment: So, you downloaded a .deb file from a website. How did you install it?

Comment: I clicked on it and it opened up the launcher. This problem is fixed now. I did not remember so I did the process again. There was a remove button. Thanks.

Comment: @IsaacSingh please consider adding a proper answer below so other folks with the same question can benefit from your discovery.

Comment: Ok then. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

1. Find the .deb file that you used to install the program.
2. Open it and it should open an install launcher.
3. There will be a red button that says remove: click it and the program will be uninstalled.

Answer (score 3):

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` - open a terminal
2. Type `sudo apt-get remove steam` and hit ↵ Enter.
3. Type `sudo apt-get purge steam` and hit ↵ Enter.
4. Type `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam` and hit ↵ Enter.
5. Exit the Terminal window.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried and it does not work. It says                                                          Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.

Comment: I am sure that usually works and I do have it installed.

Comment: check this out => [(https://askubuntu.com/questions/675636/0-upgraded-0-newly-installed-0-to-remove-and-1-not-upgraded)]

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: On the desktop it now has Steam on it. It is not uninstalled.

Comment: Try fixing the `135 not upgraded` first.

Comment: Delete the folders **~/.steam** and **~/.local/share/Steam**.

Comment: That is what I did. Well, the Steam folder that used to be there disappeared but the other I deleted.

Comment: Try this command `sudo apt-cache policy steam` & what it say?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The problem got solved. Thanks for helping me upgrade everything too.

Comment: Please consider deleting also the directories `/lib/steam/`, the `steam*` files in `/usr/bin/`, and the related repos  (steam*) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`