# `... not upgraded`. how to find out which packages?

Tags: apt, upgrade

I get this message:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How do I find out which packages are not upgraded, and why?

On many similar outputs like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675636/0-upgraded-0-newly-installed-0-to-remove-and-1-not-upgraded), it additionally prints sth like `The following packages have been kept back:`, but not in my case here.

Additionally:

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
```

Additionally:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --dry-run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get full-upgrade --dry-run
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

`apt-cache policy` log [here](https://gist.github.com/albertz/63cdaa805ec2eac5d206f734f987400e).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you do an update before you tried to do an upgrade?

Comment: @David: 20.04. And yes. But would that be related to the question? I just ask about how to find out what packages it refers to.

Comment: Add the output of `apt-get dist-upgrade --dry-run`, please

Comment: There are packages that are not upgraded with a `apt upgrade`; the `man apt` will explain why (key is the bit for "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will **remove** currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.*" which is the command that upgrades all packages.

Comment: @guiverc How can I find out which packages?

Comment: can you show `apt-cache policy` please?

Comment: I forgot Look to your apt-cache policy you pinnt 2 packages with apt pinning priority  - 1 there I would look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two packages that will not be upgraded are the ones that are pinned, to prevent them from being upgraded.

From the end of the `apt-cache policy` output:

```
Pinned packages:
     nsight-compute -> 10.1.243-3 with priority -1
     nsight-systems -> 10.1.243-3 with priority -1
```

Comment: This sounds like it is the problem. But what does this mean? How have they been pinned? Why are they pinned? Should I keep it this way or unpin it? How do I unpin? What are the consequences?

Comment: My original question here is also a bit more generic, i.e. how to figure out which packages are referred to when `apt` writes "... not upgraded". Or does it always mean there are pinned packages? Or could it mean sth else as well? This is my main question here. How to find out.

Comment: @Albert AFAIK this has to be manually done. It is done specifically to keep a package from being updated. The only packages I have pinned on my system is `snapd` to keep it from being installed. To do that, I had to go into `/etc/apt/preferences.d` and make a file that set the pin-priority negative. So to find this on your system, go into `/etc/apt` and grep for `nsight-compute`. I can't answer why it was done...because the owner of the system did it. If you are not the owner of the system, maybe you can ask them?

Comment: I'm the owner of the system but I don't remember that I did sth like that. Or rather I'm actually pretty sure I did not.

Comment: @Albert did you find `nsight-compute` referenced in `\etc\apt` somewhere? Now I'm curious. I guess there's no reason some program couldn't set  a pin. I don't even know what `nsight-compute` is.