# Get a list of 'held back' packages from apt for using with `apt-get install`?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, bash, dependencies

I know *why* they're listed as held-back, and I know what I [want to do to get them updated](https://askubuntu.com/a/185402/101189), but I've got like 100 or more packages that are held-back so it's not a simple matter of copy/pasting the list from the `apt-get upgrade` command because of the multiple lines and multiple screens worth of packages.

How can I streamline this from my current solution of copy/pasting just some of them at a time?

Comment: *sudo apt-get dist-upgrade* should take care of that automatically. If you have a problem with that please add more info, namely the errors - if any - after doing apt-get update.

Comment: I agree with @CelticWarrior The other answers on that page that is linked is saying how dangerous using `dist-upgrade` is.  I have used it many times.  Make sure that you pay attention to it wanting to install and not remove TONS of packages.  Plus, without using `dist-upgrade` there is no way to go to the next point release, i.e. 16.04.1 to 16.04.2 without manually downloading the next release from the site.

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg -l | grep ^h` shows the packages that have been held back.