# How to solve this problem 23 not upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
rakesh@rakesh-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-software gnome-software-common libapache2-mod-php liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 linux-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-generic oxideqt-codecs php-cli php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt
  php-mysql php-xml python3-software-properties qml-module-ubuntu-web
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ubuntu-software
  webapp-container webbrowser-app
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The following packages have been kept back](https://askubuntu.com/q/601/)

Answer (score 2):

The message "X not upgraded" is displayed when you install one or more packages while upgrades are available, but choose not to install the upgrades, or when you choose not to install some available upgrades while installing others.  It does no harm, as such, it's just to inform you there are upgrades that you haven't installed yet.

In your case, `apt-get upgrade -f` isn't a command to install upgrades; it only displays those that are available -- equivalent to unchecking all available upgrades in a package manager and then hitting "Apply".  If you execute `sudo apt-get upgrade` you'll tell apt to actually install all available upgrades (and their dependencies, if there are some new ones).

Comment: Yes,you are right..

Answer (score 0):

`upgrade -f` does nothing.

Please do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in order to update all the packages that have been kept back.

Comment: done that, still `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0):

If you see X not upgraded even after you run sudo apt upgrade.

I suggest you to try install individual packages.
First get the list of all the packages not upgrade by running below command

```
$ apt list --upgradable
```

Now run the below command for each package in the list

```
$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <package-name>
```

This should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).