# Releasing a package from being held back

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm afraid my `gcc` package is not being updated (version 4.9.3 on Xubuntu 16.04). My guess is someone else or myself might have mistakenly configured it to hold itself back, but I don't know who to release that lock.

I know it doesn't appear to be locked in the `synaptic` package manager interface, so it must have been done some other way.

Could you guys help me figure this one out? What are other ways to install and keep out-of-date packages?

Output of `gcc -v` (all that long "Configured with" line looks suspicious but I don't really understand it)

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-13ubuntu2)
```

EDIT:

`apt-mark showhold` has no output (empty)

`grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list` output:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main 
restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main 
restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse
```

`apt-cache policy gcc` output:

```
gcc:
  Installed: 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`which gcc`: `/usr/bin/gcc`

`whereis gcc`:

```
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

`/usr/bin/gcc -v |& tail -1` (I don't get how this one contradicts the others, what's the explanation?)

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

`update-alternatives --list gcc`:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.9
/usr/bin/gcc-5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Comment: `apt-get install gcc` or `dpkg -i gcc` should remove the hld if there is one. of course installing the new version will also fix it

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of these two command: `apt-mark showhold` and `grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Not a duplicate since `gcc` doesn't appear on the `dist-upgrade`. reinstalling `gcc` also doesn't help

Comment: @OdedSayar can you add the output of `apt-cache policy gcc` too?

Comment: You've got the last version installed... what is the output of `which gcc`? and `whereis gcc` ?

Comment: Also `/usr/bin/gcc -v |& tail -1`

Comment: Please check the output of `update-alternatives --list gcc`

Comment: so how come the regular `gcc` gives me the 4.9 while I have the updated 5.4?

Comment: It's a little bit weird... cause `which` returns the correct path, I let you know if I came up with something new.

Comment: I mean, I solved it by `sudo update-alterantives --config gcc` and choosing the 5.4, but I wonder how it got to be the default

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP found out themselves

```
sudo update-alterantives --config gcc
```

allowed them to choose a different default `gcc` version.