# Ubuntu 16.0.4 has Apache 2.4.18 in the cache but 2.4.29 is the latest release. Is it necessary to get latest version?

Tags: upgrade, apache2

Step 1) Checked the version of Ubuntu with `lsb_release -a`.  My server has 16.04.3 LTS.

Step 2) Installed Apache with `apt-get install apache2`.

Step 3) Checked the version of Apache with `apache2 -v`.  I have 2.4.18.

However according to the [Apache website](https://httpd.apache.org/) the latest version is 2.4.29.

Is it common practice or generally safe to upgrade to the latest version of Apache or other packages?  If so how would I do that?  Is there an obvious reason why I shouldn't update to the latest?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the ppa https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2 to get the latest version.

There's always some risk involved in using a ppa but this one is popular; I myself have used it for a long time without issue.

Since you already have Apache installed, you can get the update by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll use the ondrej ppa.  One question, how often does Ubuntu update it's repository?  By that I mean if I use the PPA am I typically weeks, months or years ahead of when Ubuntu updates a package?

Comment: I couldn't answer that without some research; when I first set up my website, I looked for the newest version as you are doing, found this ppa, and I've never paid any attention to what's in the official repos since then.

Comment: I've already done that, but it still won't go higher than 2.4.18. At the time of writing my server is Ubuntu 16.04.7. I've even tried the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I found that for some reason my newly installed PPA that Organic Marble posted did not work immediately not because it wasn't right it was my machine not upgrading correctly, with a little research I found that upgrading the distribution worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

this together with Organic Marble answer did the trick for me

Reference: ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)