# Not able to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, server, 18.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu server 16.04.5 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS. But it fails identify the newer release. I tried all the options, which are explained in other Q&A.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

My Current Version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

release-upgrades file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=lts
```

Comment: Did you tried [first `sudo apt update`](https://askubuntu.com/a/862799/349837)? The file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` [have `Prompt=lts`](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver#h8-1-1-upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-lts)?

Comment: Yes, I tried sudo apt update, and file release-upgrades has Prompt=lts