# Trying to upgrade from 14 to 16 (or 18) but get "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."

Tags: apt, upgrade

I've run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and think ironed out all the errors from those, but now when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` I still get:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

apt-get-update:

```
root@shop-update:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Hit:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 https://repos.sonar.digitalocean.com/apt main InRelease
Hit:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease
Hit:8 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 107 kB in 1s (97.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

apt-get upgrade:

```
root@shop-update:/# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  cloud-init
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us your latest `apt-get update` and  `apt-get upgrade` output.

Comment: And....

What version of Ubuntu do you have?

14.04.5 or 14.04.04?

Comment: Oh it appears the update did go through and im on 16, sorry to waste your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade is prevented because the output of your apt-get upgrade shows:

> The following packages have been kept back:
>       (some list of packages)

You should first resolve that.
If you intend to install the 'kept back' packages, see this answer:

> ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)