# Can't upgrade to 18.04 (due to seemingly unupgradable packages)?

Tags: upgrade

Trying to upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 (following [this](https://medium.com/@chiragpatel_52497/upgrading-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-15c1288d5f50) article) and having problem that seems to be related to packages not being upgraded, yet when trying to upgrade the packages am told that those packages cannot be upgraded. Upgrade attempt logs provided below, but not sure the best way to interpret the problem from them. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
➜  ~ /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:30: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
➜  ~ sudo apt update                                       
....
http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Hit:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Fetched 326 kB in 2s (125 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key E5220FB7014D0FBDA50DFC2BE5E86C008AA65D56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
➜  ~ apt list --upgradable                                 
Listing... Done
cuda/unknown 10.1.105-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 9.2.148-1]
cuda-drivers/unknown 418.40.04-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 396.44-1]
➜  ~ sudo apt upgrade cuda cuda-drivers                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-418-dev (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
➜  ~ sudo apt upgrade                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cuda-command-line-tools-10-0 cuda-command-line-tools-10-1 cuda-compiler-10-0 cuda-compiler-10-1
  ....
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  cuda cuda-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
➜  ~ sudo apt upgrade cuda cuda-drivers                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-418-dev (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using the answer here (https://askubuntu.com/a/602/760862)

```
sudo apt-get install <list of packages kept back>
```

from user MichaelCrenshaw