# sudo apt upgrade not working after ubuntu update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10 using the command line command `sudo do-release-upgrade` and after that, whenever I run `sudo apt upgrade`, all I see is the following: -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  bind9-host dnsutils evolution-data-server fwupdate libbind9-160 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19
  libedata-book-1.2-25 libedataserver-1.2-23 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libfwup1 libirs160 libisc169 libisccc160 libisccfg160 liblwres160
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

How can I fix this? I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 and this is getting in my way.
Also, on running `sudo apt update` I see this warning: -

```
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
```

---

EDIT: -

I got rid of the duplicates, now when I do `sudo apt update` it says: -

```
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
18 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

but on doing `sudo apt upgrade`, it's still the same.

---

EDIT 2: -

I found the solution, apparently, `sudo apt full-upgrade` did the trick. Thank you everyone for helping me out!

Comment: When packages are "kept back" without any error, first try `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Read the output *carefully* before agreeing to apt's proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate entries in your sources.list

You should check them in that file (/etc/apt/sources.list)

Another way is:

going to

System settings >> Software and Updates >> Other Software and removing each duplicate entry.

Comment: Deleted the duplicates, still doesn't fix the issue, edited the question with more info.

Comment: Sure.
Check this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it