# Unmet dependancy unity-control-center

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, dependencies, 19.04

I'm trying to bravely step forward into the "apt-world" and got these errors tonight testing upgrade from 16.04 to 19.04 on a clone (it's.. well... complicated...):

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not installable
 libdouble-conversion1v5 : Conflicts: libdouble-conversion1 but 3.1.0-2 is to be installed
                           Breaks: libdouble-conversion1 but 3.1.0-2 is to be installed
 libqt5dbus5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5network5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Does anyone know how to solve these errors or what additional information I can provide to help solve them?

The 16.04 to 19.04 upgrade is by script so I can install packages beforehand if that helps things out. I've recloned 16.04 and run the script five times to work out the other bugs and now I can almost see the light at the end of the tunnel.

---

### Reply to comments

Currently only Unity Desktop is installed and converted by upgrade. After successful upgrade I plan to install Gnome Desktop and possibly Wayland.

I see even before upgrade there is a problem:

```
$ sudo dpkg -P libdouble-conversion1v5

dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64:
 libqt5qml5:amd64 depends on libdouble-conversion1v5 (>= 2.0.0).

dpkg: error processing package libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64
```

The other item asked for:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep hw

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

hwdata/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.267-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
linux-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed]
linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-54/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0-54.58~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-55/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0-55.60~16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed]
linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed]
linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.15.0.55.76 amd64 [installed,automatic]
lshw/xenial-updates,now 02.17-1.1ubuntu3.6 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:7.7+16ubuntu3~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:7.7+16ubuntu3~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1.9.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:0.34.0-0ubuntu2~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.1~16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:7.7+16ubuntu3~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 18.0.1-1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:18.0.1-1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:0.4.4-1build6~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:1.0.15-2~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 0.1.5-2build1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:18.0.1-1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:2.3.4-1build3~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:13.2.1-1build1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

---

### The next step

I might be suffering from packages being held back:

- ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Because all three packages exist in **16.04** they just aren't being upgraded to **19.04**:

```
$ apt list unity-control-center
Listing... Done
unity-control-center/xenial-updates,now 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

$ apt list libqt5core5a
Listing... Done
libqt5core5a/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6 amd64 [installed]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

$ apt list libdouble-conversion1v5
Listing... Done
libdouble-conversion1v5/xenial,now 2.0.1-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
```

The answers in the link have many suggestions, the first one I'll try after work is:

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep hw` and `sudo dpkg -P libdouble-conversion1v5` please.  Preferred desktop Unity or gnome-shell?

Comment: @nobody Question updated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to try deeper approach with one of the commands below:

- try to get new dependencies

  ```
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- try Aptitude's safe-upgrade

  ```
  sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
  ```
- try Aptitude's dist-upgrade

  ```
  sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
  ```
- try Aptitude TUI to see broken packages

  ```
  sudo aptitude
  ```

If all these commands fail - then start over with removing obsolete packages with one of the methods:

- with `apt-get`

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- with Aptitude's TUI

  ```
  sudo aptitude
  ```

  and then navigate to *Obsolete and Locally Created Packages* and carefully remove packages from this section while controlling broken packages.

Notes:

1. on clean Ubuntu 19.04 VM I can't install `libdouble-conversion1v5` package as it [came from 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libdouble-conversion1v5).
2. I have successfully ran upgrade of Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS to 19.04 with commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo sed -i 's/xenial/disco/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   but for upgrade of default Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (with Unity) → 19.04 I was forced to use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f` several times until success and used `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/grilo-plugins*.deb` (for only this package).
3. Also I have successfully ran upgrade of Ubuntu MATE (and Unity) 16.04 LTS → 18.04 LTS → 19.04 with commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update # on 16.04 LTS
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1v5
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo do-release-upgrade # with reboot into 18.04 LTS
   sudo sed -i 's/Prompt=never/Prompt=normal/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo do-release-upgrade # to 19.04
   ```

So it seems that we need to review your upgrade script :)

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` was a complete disaster the first few times to 19.04 and 18.04 because many packages were removed. I will do some homework on `libdouble-conversion1v5` to see if I even need it in 16.04.

Comment: According to this: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/proposed/libqt5qml5 **libqt5qml5** which uses `libdoubl-conversion1v5` on 2018-09-06 11:06:44 UTC was **Moved to bionic:universe:updates**.

Comment: I'll recommend to use more official site [as LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/double-conversion/+packages), it says that in 18.04 LTS binary packages are [named without `v5`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/double-conversion). Currently I have started Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS VM, installed `libdouble-conversion1v5` library on it and I'm running `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04 LTS. I'm using `squid-deb-proxy`, so the network traffic is not the problem for me :)

Comment: How do I tell Ubuntu to use Launch Pad instead of it's default server for this app'?

Comment: I shared a link to show package origin, not to use it as APT repository :) Moreover, packages are already in the their repository. We have tracked their movement to it. It is just another helpful resource - in addition to https://packages.ubuntu.com .

Comment: Undestood. I've updated the question twice now with more details. Not sure if you caught both revisions.

Comment: Accepting your answer and moving on as 16.04 to 19.04 is now successful. FTR to fix the above errors a simple `sudo apt purge package_name` did the trick. There were other complications with held back packages and apt-daily.service running on boot but they were all solved with existing Q&A here in **Ask Ubuntu**.