# sudo apt install errors

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, dependencies, pip

when i run

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev wget libbz2-dev -y && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz && tar -xf Python-3.8.2.tgz && cd Python-3.8.2 && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make -j 8 && sudo make altinstall
```

the output is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
wget is already the newest version (1.19.4-1ubuntu2.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5) but 1.1.1c-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks like you added some non-Ubuntu source that upgraded your libssl1.1, Remove that source and all packages that came from that source. Then apt will work again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update your system first?

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

If you have "kept-back" packages I would refer you to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/602/1075577)