# apt-get upgrade with and without "--with-new-pkgs" What is the difference? why do I continue to see kept back packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I ran apt-get upgrade and found a kept back package.

```
bitnami@ip-xxxxx-xx-xxx:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) and after some basic understanding of what "--with-new-pkgs-upgrade" does, I ran the following:

```
bitnami@ip-xxxxx-xx-xxx:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, when I rerun the regular "apt-get upgrade" again, I still see the kept back packages listed.

```
bitnami@ip-xxxxx-xx-xxx:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

The link I'm referring to also provides a troubleshooting step in one of the comments:

I ran the step to just find it doesn't do anything and reports 0 not upgraded:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I still see the kept back packages. Is there any benefit of "--with-new-pkgs"? How do solve the issue with kept-back packages in this case?

Comment: Depends upon the the reason *why* the package was kept back. "--with-new-pkgs" is rarely the reason, though it it does occasionally happen. The two main reasons are 1) Package name change (like a kernel bump; solve by using `sudo apt full-upgrade`) or 2) A version conflict ("*Foo 1.1, but 1.2.is already installed*"), usually from a non-Ubuntu source, that must be solved.

Comment: Thank you. I understand reason 1, but with reason 2 how can we resolve a conflict with a package installed from a  non-ubuntu source? How can we even determine that I is the issue? by going to the source list? I thought the `apt` usually tells me if there is a conflict but not sure why it doesn't state that now.

Comment: If apt isn't complaining, then there may be no conflict. Your 3rd set of output indicates no problems and no kept-back packages. Your comment "*I still see the kept back packages*" indicates that you might be looking at something different. If so, edit your question to show us.