# Unselectable software updates

Tags: update-manager

Running 20.04, the software updater shows several updates which are not selected to install by default, and which I cannot choose to install: clicking on them does nothing.  Please see the image below.  Several questions:

- Why is this happening?
- Did I do something wrong? (And if so, what?)
- Is there something I should do now?

[image]

A few days later, I get this update:

[image]

In response to the first comment:

If the update requires root permission, then I am asked for the pasword after selecting to install it.

I did as you suggested, but can't see the odd entries;  this is the result:

Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [61.7 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [160 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.3 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4,176 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.1 kB]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [195 kB]
Get:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [325 kB]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [8,428 B]
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [84.6 kB]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [155 kB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [184 kB]
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Fetched 1,672 kB in 2s (888 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong there. However it seems unusual that you cannot select them. Are you logged in as the root user? You can always update using the terminal command `sudo apt-get update` and note if it includes those unselectable ones from above.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and put the result in the question as it's too long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I am certain you are not missing out on anything important but cannot say why you are unable to select those packages. Just an oddity of that gui it seems. If you go to **Show Applications** and search for **Software & Updates** then you may see more options under the tabs **Ubuntu Software** or **Other Software** or **Updates** that your system will either look for or ignore come update time.

Comment: Sorry - go to Show Applications where?

Comment: On 20.04 there is an icon in the sidebar that is like 9 dots forming a square. OR from the dropdown at the top right select "Settings" then "Applications" and use the search for "Software & Updates" - don't select "Software Updater".

Comment: Apologies - what you said was quite clear with hindsight.  It even says 'Show Applications' when I hover over those nine dots.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an oddity of the GUI, as the problem remains after doing upgrades via the command line.

What I'm seeing appears to be what happens when this is the situation:
[The following packages have been kept back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

There is an extended discussion, but in summary, it should resolve itself in time.