# Which install or configuration changes into LTS make it lose its LTS essence?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, configuration, lts, support

Whenever I see `Long Term Support (LTS)` I think about trust in the stability of the system for some period. I hope that the packages were carefully selected so that their life cycle and the one of their dependencies are ensured not to create conflicts or deployment problems for a while.

Is there some install or configuration actions that I should prevent in order to lose that trust ?

For example: changing some config files, manually installing packages / PPAs / snaps with certain rights, or even solving dependency problems like [packages kept back](https://askubuntu.com/a/602/360354).

Is there some command that shows me:

`Your LTS compatibility is 100%`

or something like that ?

Comment: LTS just mean that the period that Canonical will update the packages present at release time for, is longer.  This was a problem earlier for Java as the new releases were very desired by the community but the packages were not pre-provided to put them in.  This was later the case for the Java 11 LTS release which was not ready but would be later within the LTS support period.

Comment: what you might be looking for is `ubuntu-security-status` better yet have a look here https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't confuse *support* and *stability*.

LTS releases offer "stability" in the sense that *the software does not change for 5 years*, not the sense that *it crashes less often*. The latter coincidentally does happen to be somewhat true also, but that's due to the large user base discovering and filing bugs.

---

The best way to keep any release of Ubuntu operating stably (less likely to crash) is to stick to the Ubuntu repositories and Snaps when installing software.

The easy way to make an LTS install unstable (more likely to crash) is to install a lot of non-Ubuntu, PPA, and/or wrong-version software onto it. These are, of course, exactly the same ways that you get dependency problems.

A common problem occurs when folks mistakenly consider an LTS to be a "stable base system" that they can bolt newer software onto. This is precisely the opposite of what an LTS is designed for. If you want newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu. The Interim (6-month) releases are just as stable for most users as LTS... AND have newer kernel and software.

---

For a command that details how far from any release (including LTS) that you have drifted, try `ubuntu-security-status`

```
$ ubuntu-security-status 
2258 packages installed, of which:
1745 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
 499 could receive security updates with ESM Apps until 4/2030
   1 package is from a third party
  13 packages are no longer available for download
```

Here you can see that I have 14 packages to investigate out of 2258 packages on the system (0.6%). Try it: The output includes instructions on how to get more detail on each category.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115252/discussion-on-answer-by-user535733-which-install-or-configuration-changes-into-l).