# Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading. Can't upgrade to 20.10 from 20.04.1

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

In order, i've attempted:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
4. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

After running the last step, it resulted in `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading`.  i also tried the above in order with just `apt` and not `apt-get` (per a prior post on askUbuntu)...i get the same message after getting to step 4.  i tried running `sudo apt autoremove` after the upgrade step, but that didn't do it.  i tried removing packages that weren't able to be upgraded after running step 2, but that didn't do it (there was a dotnet-sdk that couldn't be upgrade).  notify is set to any new version of ubuntu.  also tried running steps 1-3 then `sudo update-manager`, but i get the same message. my release from `lsb_release -a` is

- `Dist ID - Ubuntu`
- `Desc - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`
- `Release - 20.04`
- `Codename - focal`

my 3rd party sources are:

- http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu
- https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb
- http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/

EDIT:

disabling teamviewer and chrome in my 3rd party sources resolved the error.

Comment: There's no such thing as Ubuntu 20.1 and there's no Ubuntu 20.X that comes before 20.04.  It's also clear that you're not aware what commands do before you run them. #1 does something different than #2&#3 which do something entirely different than #4.  What is it exactly that you want to do?  What release are you actually running right now?

Comment: Please give us the **entire** unredacted output of each command if you want help with these errors. There's no way you are getting the same single line error for all of these. Please make sure that you retain line breaks and continue to use monospace formatting

Comment: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* for main desktop & server releases, and *year* for reduced functionality thus smaller specialist releases. There was no release in 2020-January (20.1).  Usual problems on *release-upgrade* are added 3rd party packages, OR holds (`apt-mark`) put on packages that prevent upgrade. If it's uninstalled upgraded packages, your messages will provide the clues, but as we can't see them, we can't help except to tell you to read all messages.

Comment: @Nmath i listed my release in the original post.  i've edited the post as i see i made a typo on 20.1 (added the leading zero).  as far as not being aware of the commands i'm running...i'd disagree with you as i've been an avid user of linux for well over 20 years now :) i think my lack of detail in my post unfortunately confused users rather than help...my apologies!

Comment: Hat the `Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading` too. I then tried to follow the advice here, but it did not help. But I noticed a `The following packages have been kept back` warning. It seems this equally blocks an upgrade. I was able to resolve this using https://askubuntu.com/a/602.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disabling teamviewer and chrome in my 3rd party sources resolved the error.   thank you [guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc) for leading me in the right direction with my confusing post :)

Answer (score 9):

> sudo apt list --upgradable -a

This was my friend.

Comment: After seeing the full list, do "sudo apt upgrade" and then the name of the package; the phrase before the "/"