# Not able to update softwares on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and update-manager is asking for updating a couple of software frequently automatically (check attached screenshot).

Since a couple of weeks, I am not able to select any software to update (not able to click on checkboxes, it's disabled)  (check the attached screenshot for better understanding)

Any help would be appriciated. [image]

**UPDATE**: Please check below output of `update` and `upgrade`

```
root@vishal-ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease
Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:5 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates InRelease                                                                              
Hit:6 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-backports InRelease                                                                            
Hit:7 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-security InRelease                                                                             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                            
Get:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial Release [6,600 B]          
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Fetched 6,600 B in 1s (3,981 B/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
root@vishal-ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host ca-certificates dnsutils file firefox firefox-locale-en google-chrome-stable intel-microcode libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libbind9-140 libdns-export162
  libdns162 libexif12 libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjpeg-turbo8 libjson-c2 libldap-2.4-2 liblwres141 libmagic1 libpq-dev
  libpq5 libprocps4 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libsnapd-glib1 libsqlite3-0 libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1
  libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1
  libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 openssl postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6
  postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.6 procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils snapd snapd-xdg-open thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us tzdata ubuntu-core-launcher
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libopenexr22 libp11-kit0 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libproxy1v5 p11-kit p11-kit-modules python-apt-common python3-apt update-notifier update-notifier-common
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,029 kB/1,262 kB of archives.
After this operation, 212 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 update-notifier amd64 3.168.13 [47.5 kB]
Get:2 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 update-notifier-common all 3.168.13 [133 kB]
Get:3 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 p11-kit-modules amd64 0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2 [73.7 kB]
Get:4 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 libp11-kit0 amd64 0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2 [107 kB]
Get:5 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 libopenexr22 amd64 2.2.0-10ubuntu2.4 [593 kB]
Get:6 http://ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in xenial-updates/main amd64 p11-kit amd64 0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2 [75.0 kB]
Fetched 1,029 kB in 1s (975 kB/s)  
(Reading database ... 325147 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../update-notifier_3.168.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking update-notifier (3.168.13) over (3.168.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-apt-common_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-apt-common (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11) over (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apt_1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11) over (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../update-notifier-common_3.168.13_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-notifier-common (3.168.13) over (3.168.10) ...
Preparing to unpack .../p11-kit-modules_0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) over (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libp11-kit0_0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libp11-kit0:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) over (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libopenexr22_2.2.0-10ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenexr22:amd64 (2.2.0-10ubuntu2.4) over (2.2.0-10ubuntu2.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager_0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) over (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) over (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libproxy1v5_0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) over (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../p11-kit_0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking p11-kit (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) over (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python-apt-common (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11) ...
Setting up python3-apt (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.11) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.13) ...
Setting up update-notifier (3.168.13) ...
Setting up libp11-kit0:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) ...
Setting up p11-kit-modules:amd64 (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) ...
Setting up libopenexr22:amd64 (2.2.0-10ubuntu2.4) ...
Setting up libproxy1v5:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:amd64 (0.4.11-5ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up p11-kit (0.23.2-5~ubuntu16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...
```

Please note, I am getting below popup while `upgrade` as well as when I start the computer first time
[image]

**UPDATE-2**

```
root@vishal-ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host ca-certificates dnsutils file firefox firefox-locale-en google-chrome-stable intel-microcode libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 libbind9-140 libdns-export162
  libdns162 libexif12 libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140 libjpeg-turbo8 libjson-c2 libldap-2.4-2 liblwres141 libmagic1 libpq-dev
  libpq5 libprocps4 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libsnapd-glib1 libsqlite3-0 libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1
  libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1 libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1
  libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 openssl postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6
  postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.6 procps pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils snapd snapd-xdg-open thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us tzdata ubuntu-core-launcher
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
```

```
root@vishal-ubuntu:~# ls -l /var/crash
total 312
-rw------- 1 root whoopsie 315499 Dec 31 19:46 oracle-java11-installer-local.0.crash
```

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt-get update` and then run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Copy of the complete output of both commands and paste it into your question (copy/paste, not screenshot, please).

Comment: @user535733 Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated the question as requested by you. Can you please help now?

Comment: We are already helping you...by guiding you to provide the information needed to answer your question. Next, add the complete output of the following two commands into your question: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `ls -l /var/crash`

Comment: The part of your output that you are tracking down is: `11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **93 not upgraded.**` Could be several possible causes. Each cause gets fixed differently.

Comment: Hi @user535733 Thank you, question updated. Just for note, the crashed one library (java 11) which I tried to install recently but I could not select checkboxes while update since long time

Comment: Then they seem to be separate problems, and I will ignore the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the problem is a version-incompatible package, likely somewhere among the list of kept-back packages.

Package X requires dependency A.1, but the rest of the group of packages requires dependency A.2.

Since apt cannot install both A.1 and A.2, it cannot update any of the listed packages.

1. The easiest way to fix the problem is to search your memory: Whatever the last thing you installed before the problem began is the likely culprit for Package X. Uninstall it. and see if that fixes the problem.

   - Use your apt history logs in `/var/log/apt` to see your install history and help you remember.
2. The more tedious way is to run `apt-cache policy <packagename>` on each listed package, looking for the origin of the package. The culprit for Package X is the package(s) that is not from the official Ubuntu repositories, or is from a wrong-version repository.

   - Packages in the Ubuntu repositories are *specifically* tested to prevent this kind of problem.
3. The `aptitude` application, provided by the `aptitude` package has a visual solver that can be very helpful to identify the problematic Package X, and to suggest alternative solutions. You may-or-may-not be able to install `aptitude`.
4. Keep in mind that your release of Ubuntu (16.04) reaches the end of Community Support quite soon (April 2021), so expending a lot of effort may not be worthwhile. Another alternative is to begin migrating your data to a clean-installed Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my answer because it might be helpful for someone else. I found the very easy solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/602/286126 --> "Cautious solution 2:"

It worked very well