# apt showing 2 packaged not upgraded, how do I know which ones?

Tags: apt, upgrade, held-packages

`apt` reports that there are 2 packages that were not upgraded and does not tell me which ones those are. `apt list --upgradable` shows nothing.

I tried `apt update` then `apt upgrade` as well as `apt dist-upgrade`. No luck. Logs below.

Also: there's a related [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) on how to solve the problem, but it assumes `apt` would inform me which packages it held back.

---

```
user@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt update
... # long list of successful pulls 
Fetched 109 kB in 3s (36.1 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
user@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

```bsh
user@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

```
user@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt list --upgradeable
Listing... Done
```

```
user@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt-show-versions | grep upgrad
python3-distupgrade:all/focal-updates 1:20.04.32 uptodate
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all/focal-updates 1:20.04.32 uptodate
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all/focal-updates 1:20.04.32 uptodate
unattended-upgrades:all/focal-updates 2.3ubuntu0.1 uptodate
```

Comment: The next thing to try is `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade` .

Comment: @N0rbert, same result. Nothing listed, `No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed`, `0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`