# resolve kept back packages on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Hi I recently upgraded the OS from Ubuntu18.04 to Ubuntu20.04. Now I notice that when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I have packages kept back:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  build-essential cpp g++ gcc gfortran liblapack-dev liblapack3
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

I tried the methods mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it).
To resolve this I tried

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but the output is the same as before.

I also tried
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
and the solution is also to keep the packages at their current version. The output is the following:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-9{ab} g++-9{ab} gcc-9{ab} gfortran-9{ab} libasan5{ab} libgcc-9-dev{ab} libgfortran-9-dev{ab} libgfortran5{ab} libstdc++-9-dev{ab} 
  libubsan1{ab} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  build-essential cpp g++ gcc gfortran liblapack-dev liblapack3 
7 packages upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 170 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-9 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgfortran-9-dev : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libasan5 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libstdc++-9-dev : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libubsan1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1 is installed
 g++-9 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~18.04~1 is installed
 gcc-9 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 gfortran-9 : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
 libgcc-9-dev : Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) but 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      build-essential [12.4ubuntu1 (now)]                
2)      cpp [4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 (now)]                     
3)      cpp-9 [Not Installed]                              
4)      g++ [4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 (now)]                     
5)      g++-9 [Not Installed]                              
6)      gcc [4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 (now)]                     
7)      gcc-9 [Not Installed]                              
8)      gfortran [4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3 (now)]                
9)      gfortran-9 [Not Installed]                         
10)     libasan5 [Not Installed]                           
11)     libgcc-9-dev [Not Installed]                       
12)     libgfortran-9-dev [Not Installed]                  
13)     libgfortran5 [Not Installed]                       
14)     liblapack-dev [3.7.1-4ubuntu1 (now)]               
15)     liblapack3 [3.7.1-4ubuntu1 (now)]                  
16)     libstdc++-9-dev [Not Installed]                    
17)     libubsan1 [Not Installed]
```

Can someone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `gcc-9-base` as an example: No Ubuntu repositories have version `9.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04`, so that's from a non-Ubuntu source. Whatever source that is, you should have uninstalled those packages before upgrading.

Comment: Hi@user535733 Thanks for the valuable insight. I remove gcc-9-base and gcc-10-base and manually install them. Now the issue has been solved.

Comment: Best practice is to keep track of packages that you install from non-Ubuntu sources. Uninstall those packages before you release upgrade -- return your system to as close to stock condition as possible to avoid hiccups like this. After the release-upgrade is completely successful, you can decide if you still need the non-Ubuntu packages or not, and re-install those that you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out I need to `sudo apt-get remove gcc-9-base` and then `sudo apt-get install gcc-9-base`. Same thing needs to done for gcc-10-base as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar error, with the gcc-9-base package. What worked for me was:

- *Check for available versions*.
  Like this:

  ```
  $ apt-cache madison gcc-9-base
  ```

The result may look something like this:

```
gcc-9-base | 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
gcc-9-base | 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
gcc-9-base | 9.3.0-10ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

- *Choose the needed version*, in this case 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04, and *install* like this:

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install gcc-9-base=9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  ```

apt-get should manage to fix your broken packages now.

**P.S.: I know this question is a bit old now, but here's the solution for anyone that has had a similar problem.**

Answer (score 0):

[PLNewbie's answer works](https://askubuntu.com/a/1343967/941887): `apt remove` and `install` [*packagename*] resolves issues with packages "kept back."

`apt install [*packagename*]` without first removing [*packagename*] is also working so far. e.g.

> `sudo apt install nftables`

This has resolved a handful of packages "kept back" since upgrading to 22.04[0]. It appears update or overwrite the previous version of same:

`sudo apt list -ia nftables`

```
Listing... Done 
nftables/jammy-updates,now 1.0.2-1ubuntu3 amd64
[installed] nftables/jammy 1.0.2-1ubuntu2 amd64
```

[0] via **Software Updater** prompt and without explicit `dist-upgrade` by me.

Comment: This method still has unresolved issues. I've seen a few packages recur to "kept back" after previous explicit installs without first removal. The issue has occurred with ~20 packages. It's occurring less frequently.  

and my manual intervention "encourages" me to pay more attention to what `apt` and `snap` are doing. I'm not yet ready for `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or other higher-level / coarser-grained approaches.

Answer (score -1):

For a little more explanation, when a package is "kept back", that means that there is a new version of it available, but installing that new version would involve removing some packages or installing other new ones, and the `upgrade` command won't do that automatically.

You want to instead use the `install` command; e. g.:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cpp g++ gcc gfortran liblapack-dev liblapack3
```

This will also install (or remove) any other packages that are necessary to satisfy those upgrades.  Read over the output from this carefully before you accept it; if the reason a package is kept back is because the new version conflicts with another package you have installed, apt may want to resolve the problem by removing that package, so double-check anything it says it's going to remove to make sure that's acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually tried this earlier but it still simply keep back the packages as using sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: If it still keeps the packages back, that can means that the packages you're trying to upgrade conflict with each other.  That can be a real pain to diagnose, but sometimes installing them one at a time until you run into a package that is trying to remove one of the others.