# Can't upgrade certain files in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: package-management, upgrade, uninstall, update-manager

Recently installed Ubuntu. After a month I tried to upgrade all the packages but 5 of them got held back and I couldn't figure out why.

I ran the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and now running upgrade command shows no packages are held back but running update command still shows the earlier packages.

```
priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
[sudo] password for priyanshu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libllvm12:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-470
  libnvidia-common-470 libnvidia-compute-470:i386 libnvidia-decode-470 libnvidia-decode-470:i386 libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-encode-470:i386 libnvidia-extra-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386
  libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-gl-470:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libva-wayland2 libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
  libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxnvctrl0 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-27 linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic linux-modules-5.11.0-27-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-27-generic linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-27-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-27-generic mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  nvidia-utils-470 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
priyanshu@Inspiron-7501:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]   
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (86.9 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
```

Also should I remove the packages terminal is asking me to remove or are there risks.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`.

Comment: It is likely a dependency issue, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Comment: Also try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm quite sceptical about the command as it auto-removes packages. Is it safe to trust the system to remove packages