# Ubuntu Software updater dies on upgrade

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am currently running 21.04.  I would like to upgrade to 21.10, but when I try to start the upgrade by clicking on the button (see image) the window simply closes and that's it.

[image: Screenshot]

Nothing is written to `/var/log/apt/history.log`or `term.log`

I have run
`sudo do-release-upgrade` from the command line with the following response:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
```

I changed my sources.list file as instructed here:[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)
but when running `sudo apt-get update` I get

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Release
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Ign:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
Err:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.123 80]
```

If I then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  cuda cuda-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I changed my source.list file to use archive instead of old-releases, ran `sudo apt update`, which ran normally. I then ran ``sudo apt dist-upgrade```, which gave

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`

I then ran

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

With these results:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
```

Comment: Open a terminal and try to run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, if you get an error, add it to your question.

Comment: [Ubuntu 21.04 is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/); thus mirrors can *drop* it anytime they wish...  I provided the EOL notice as it contains a link to the *ImpishUpgrades* notice which is what I'd read, but note if you delay too long, the *release-upgrade* gets more complicated..

Comment: Thanks, I read the notice but the instructions give the same result. I am trying to connect to different servers, but so far its always the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: I would likely check if you're using the main archive, or a mirror, ensure it's still present (given it's EOL & mirrors can drop it; main archive is already past it's being *moved*) and ensure you've applied all updates for *hirsute* (21.04).  I would then reboot if required (due updates) and see if it'll `do-release-upgrade` again...  If it doesn't, and it's a desktop system (*as it looks like it is given you've provided a picture*) I'd just *upgrade via re-install*; ie. download 21.10, verify, write to media, boot that & install over existing partition(s) without format to upgrade that way.

Comment: ...  do not want to backup first, and given system directories are wiped (*before install but after manually installed packages are noted*) server apps may lose their configs so they'll need to be restored.. this won't apply with desktop apps. The *upgrade via reinstall* will automatically re-install the *manually installed* packages you had installed IF available for the new release in Ubuntu repositories. I QA-test this regularly (*did one earlier today*) and used it for my ex-21.04 support installs too.

Comment: @pLumo, I tried but without success. I added the results to the question.

Comment: @guiverc,  This seems like the nuclear option, but will try it if all else fails. Thanks!

Comment: It's not what I'd call a *nuclear* option, in that no user file is touched, no desktop configuration is touched, and the *manually installed* packages (from Ubuntu repositories) are re-installed automatically too... ie. it's my backup *fix* if I have problems with the *release-upgrade* (or my first step if I'm in a hurry as it takes only *minutes* which is much faster than *release-upgrade*...)...  In my QA-test I have my non-standard music player continue playing my *playlist* after re-install to confirm nothing was touched...  ie. that's not *nuclear* in my books...

Comment: @guiverc, thums up emoji

Comment: The *old-releases* doesn't yet apply as per my EOL notice... ie. its scheduled to occur any time now, but hasn't yet as the notice stated.

Comment: Your specific problem seems right there in your output: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded`. You didn't complete Step 1 and fully update your system before starting the release-upgrade.

Comment: @user535733, interesting, because after running ```sudo apt-get update``` I did get the following message: ```2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
(base) jon@cave-2:~$ apt list --upgradable``` . These two packages are ```cuda-drivers/unknown 510.47.03-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 495.29.05-1]
cuda/unknown 11.6.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 11.5.1-1]```

Comment: Try running `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: @Someone. Results: ```The following packages have been kept back:
  cuda cuda-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.```

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Comment: @pLumo - bingo!  Cautious solution 1 - no effect. Cautious solution 2 did result in installing the two cuda packages. I did the restart, as recommended by the command output and then tried the Software Updated.  Hitting upgrade opened the password entry window (which hasn't happened until now) and after that I am now seeing the 21.10 release notes. It looks like this issue is resolved. I will now go ahead with the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the main issue is that I had two manually installed packages (cuda, cuda-drivers) that were not updating.

As per the answer here: [askubuntu.com/questions/601](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) I needed to

> Cautious solution 2:
>
> The cautious solution is to run sudo apt-get install [list of packages
> kept back]. In most cases this will give the kept-back packages what
> they need to successfully upgrade.

`sudo apt-get install cuda cuda-drivers`

installed these packages. I did a restart as instructed by the above commands output and then tried to initiate the upgrade via the Software Updater. This seems to have solve the issue.