# Ubuntu Linux doesn't recognise my external monitor on USB-C

Tags: kernel, 21.10, external-monitor, usb-c

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. Recently, I the USB-C monitor (the HDMI is still working), it use to work with 5.13.0-35-generic but after another upgrade it doesn't work anymore.

Can anyone help?

More Information when I try to upgrade

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for yoram: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-510 libnvidia-compute-510 libnvidia-decode-510
  libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510 libnvidia-gl-510
  linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04 nvidia-compute-utils-510
  nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-kernel-common-510 nvidia-kernel-source-510
  nvidia-utils-510 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

How do I force them to Install?

Regards

Yoram

Comment: Hello. I do not see anything that needs help. Sometimes a different kernel is needed for a certain config or piece of hardware. If that kernel works use it.

Comment: So I need to stay with a lower version of Linux Kernel? I don't understand the solution...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Comment: Having the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with the 510 nvidia drivers. My HDMI monitor comes to life, while my USB-C monitor does not. The same monitor was connected 5 mins ago to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, so i rule out monitor issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end it was because the packages were held back

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-cfg1-510
```

installed all of the packages held back and sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my new HP Pavillion Gaming 15(Nvidia 3050 TI). I'm trying to solve it as well, but it looks that you need to guess which kernel is compatible with your graphic card.

"Easy" solution is to go to "Software Updates" on Ubuntu, go to settings on bottom left, press additional drivers and check the first option on top and press apply. In my case it's Nvidia 510 and then reboot.

Next problem you're gonna face is if your laptop goes to suspend mode it doesn't work normally unless you unplug external monitor and connect it back again.(At least in my case)

Comment: More Information when I try to upgrade

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
  libnvidia-cfg1-510 libnvidia-compute-510 libnvidia-decode-510
  libnvidia-encode-510 libnvidia-extra-510 libnvidia-fbc1-510 libnvidia-gl-510
  linux-modules-nvidia-510-generic-hwe-20.04 nvidia-compute-utils-510
  nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-kernel-common-510 nvidia-kernel-source-510
  nvidia-utils-510 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

Maybe I should force them to Install?