# "The following packages have been kept back" after upgrading to 22.04 on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having a problem updating Ubuntu on WSL2. I had Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed by default but used [this method](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/installing-ubuntu-20-10-on-wsl/18941) to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. But now when I run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

... to upgrade the system,  it returns:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cpp-10 cryptsetup-run gcc-10-base libaom0 libappindicator3-1 libcbor0.6
  libdav1d4 libevent-2.1-7 libidn11 libopeniscsiusr0.2.0 libpoppler107
  libpoppler111 liburcu6 libwmf-0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7 libx265-192 ltrace lz4
  python3-simplejson python3-twisted-bin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  evolution-data-server fwupd gdb gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gjs
  glib-networking glib-networking-services gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-remote-desktop gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common
  gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common gnome-startup-applications gsettings-desktop-schemas
  gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x libayatana-appindicator3-1
  libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26
  libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libegl-mesa0
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgbm1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g
  libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglx-mesa0 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgoa-1.0-0b
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-4-1 libgtk-4-bin libgweather-3-16 libinput-bin libinput10
  libintl-perl libintl-xs-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldb2 libllvm12
  liblocale-gettext-perl libnetplan0 libnewt0.52 libp11-kit0
  libproc-processtable-perl libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp
  libpython3-stdlib librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
  libsane-common libsane1 libsemanage-common libsmbclient libsnmp40 libtalloc2
  libterm-readkey-perl libtevent0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
  libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxatracker2 libyelp0
  mesa-vulkan-drivers mutter netplan.io ntfs-3g open-vm-tools p11-kit
  p11-kit-modules passwd perl perl-base pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-utils python3 python3-apt python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend
  python3-cups python3-dbus python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-gi
  python3-jinja2 python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-markupsafe
  python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-newt python3-protobuf
  python3-pyrsistent python3-simplejson python3-systemd python3-talloc
  python3-yaml python3-zope.interface rygel samba-libs sane-utils
  ubuntu-session vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xwayland yaru-theme-gnome-shell yelp
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 154 not upgraded.
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: which steps from that link did you take? It has like 3 different options

Comment: Agree with @Esther -- Please list the exact steps you took.  Also a heads-up that Canonical purposefully "holds back" LTS `do-release-upgrade`'s until the first point release so that they can iron out problems with the process.  The point release is scheduled for (IIRC) the first week in August.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it