# Failed release upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: upgrade, updates

Getting an error to run all updates, which I have shows 4 files NOT being upgraded. Here is the list (pasted from CL), ANY help would be appreciated, these files will not upgrade...

gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.4-0ubuntu1]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.06-2ubuntu10]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10]
shim-signed/jammy-updates 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The following packages have been kept back:" Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)

Answer (score 0):

The kept-back packages are currently undergoing phased upgrades. See https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html:

You can also verify this by running apt policy <package_name> on each of the kept-back packages.

You have two options:

1. You can simply wait until phasing is done, usually in a few days. However, some take longer if a problem/bug/regression was reported with the upgrade.
2. Alternately, you can force the upgrades using `sudo apt -o APT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=true upgrade`. Of course, that means you are volunteering to test those packages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll probably follow your first suggestion and wait.