# nvidia driver package is broken

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm having a problem after trying to upgrade. The message shown is:

```
cuda-drivers-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (>= 535.54.03) but it is not installed
nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.54.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please read through https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me in Ubuntu 22.04 after a routine normal update. I was able to resolve it like instructed at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it).

First:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Second:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Just in case there are broken packages (half-installed).

Third:

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade <list of packages held back>
```

In my case they where:

```
libnvidia-cfg1-535 libnvidia-common-535 libnvidia-compute-535 libnvidia-compute-535:i386 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-decode-535:i386 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-encode-535:i386  libnvidia-extra-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libnvidia-gl-535 libnvidia-gl-535:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-535 nvidia-dkms-535 nvidia-driver-530 nvidia-driver-535  nvidia-kernel-common-535 nvidia-kernel-source-535 nvidia-utils-535 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535
```

But they can be different depending on your configuration so just copy them from the result of `apt upgrade`. But remember to remove the new line characters.

And finally:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

In case there are packages not needed anymore.

I hope this helps more people. The question is poorly asked but it is one of the first results in search engines.