# Unmet dependencies but "apt --fix-broken install" does not work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies

My `nvidia-smi` does not work:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried the commands in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479481/nvidia-driver-package-is-broken)

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade nvidia-kernel-common-535
sudo apt autoremove
```

but my computer still pops out the error

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-dkms-535:
Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (=535.154.05-0ubuntu1) but 535.129.03-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However, my `nvcc -V` still works

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_15_22:02:13_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.140
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0
```

my ubuntu: 22.04

Does any one knows how to fix it? Thank you very much.

For `apt-cache policy nvidia-kernel-common-535`:

```
sudo apt-cache policy nvidia-kernel-common-535

nvidia-kernel-common-535:
  Installed: 535.129.03-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 535.154.05-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     535.154.05-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
     535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
 *** 535.129.03-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     535.104.12-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
     535.104.05-0ubuntu1 600
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  Packages
     535.104.05-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
     535.86.10-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
     535.54.03-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
```

For `sudo apt update`:

```
sudo apt update

Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1572 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local  InRelease [1575 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local  InRelease [1572 B]
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:4 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [559 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1320 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1035 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [682 kB]
Fetched 3825 kB in 5s (754 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
89 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and `apt list --upgradable`:

```
apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done
alsa-ucm-conf/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.9 all [upgradable from: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.8]
apparmor/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2]
apt-utils/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
apt/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
base-files/jammy-updates 12ubuntu4.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 12ubuntu4.4]
bind9-dnsutils/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
bind9-host/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
bind9-libs/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
binutils-common/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
binutils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
cuda-toolkit-12-config-common/unknown 12.3.101-1 all [upgradable from: 12.2.140-1]
cuda-toolkit-config-common/unknown 12.3.101-1 all [upgradable from: 12.2.140-1]
distro-info-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.52ubuntu0.6 all [upgradable from: 0.52ubuntu0.4]
distro-info/jammy-updates 1.1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1ubuntu0.1]
dnsmasq-base/jammy-updates 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3]
evince-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 all [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
evince/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
firmware-sof-signed/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.0-1ubuntu4.4 all [upgradable from: 2.0-1ubuntu4.1]
fonts-noto-color-emoji/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.042-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2.038-0ubuntu1]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gjs/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
google-chrome-stable/stable 121.0.6167.85-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 118.0.5993.88-1]
irqbalance/jammy-updates 1.8.0-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8.0-1build1]
libapparmor1/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2]
libapt-pkg6.0/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
libbinutils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libcryptsetup12/jammy-updates 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1]
libctf-nobfd0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libctf0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libevdocument3-4/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
libevview3-3/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
libfprint-2-2/jammy-updates 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.06 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.04]
libgjs0g/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
libgnutls30/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.3]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libmm-glib0/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
libnetplan0/jammy-updates 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.3]
libnss-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libpam-modules-bin/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-modules/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-runtime/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 all [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libpam0g/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libsgutils2-2/jammy-updates 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.46-1build1]
libssh-4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libssh-gcrypt-4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libssl3/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
libssl3/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 i386 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
libsystemd0/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libudev1/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libxnvctrl0/unknown 545.23.08-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.104.12-0ubuntu1]
linux-firmware/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.24 all [upgradable from: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.19]
linux-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-libc-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-92.102 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0-91.101]
modemmanager/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
netplan.io/jammy-updates 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.3]
nvidia-kernel-common-535/unknown 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.129.03-0ubuntu1]
nvidia-settings/unknown 545.23.08-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.104.12-0ubuntu1]
openssl/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
openvpn/jammy-updates 2.5.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.5.5-1ubuntu3.1]
python3-distro-info/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.1ubuntu0.2 all [upgradable from: 1.1ubuntu0.1]
python3-paramiko/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2.9.3-0ubuntu1.2 all [upgradable from: 2.9.3-0ubuntu1]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
python3-update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
software-properties-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
systemd-hwe-hwdb/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 249.11.5 all [upgradable from: 249.11.3]
systemd-oomd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd-sysv/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd-timesyncd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
transmission-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 all [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
transmission-gtk/jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
tzdata/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04 all [upgradable from: 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 30~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 29.4~22.04]
ubuntu-drivers-common/jammy-updates 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.4]
udev/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
update-manager-core/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
xserver-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 all [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xephyr/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xorg-core/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xorg-legacy/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xwayland/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.9]
(base) levi@levi:~$ apt upgrade
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
(base) levi@levi:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
alsa-ucm-conf/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.9 all [upgradable from: 1.2.6.3-1ubuntu1.8]
apparmor/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2]
apt-utils/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
apt/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
base-files/jammy-updates 12ubuntu4.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 12ubuntu4.4]
bind9-dnsutils/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
bind9-host/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
bind9-libs/jammy-updates 1:9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.3]
binutils-common/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
binutils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
cuda-toolkit-12-config-common/unknown 12.3.101-1 all [upgradable from: 12.2.140-1]
cuda-toolkit-config-common/unknown 12.3.101-1 all [upgradable from: 12.2.140-1]
distro-info-data/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.52ubuntu0.6 all [upgradable from: 0.52ubuntu0.4]
distro-info/jammy-updates 1.1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.1ubuntu0.1]
dnsmasq-base/jammy-updates 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3]
evince-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 all [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
evince/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
firmware-sof-signed/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.0-1ubuntu4.4 all [upgradable from: 2.0-1ubuntu4.1]
fonts-noto-color-emoji/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.042-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [upgradable from: 2.038-0ubuntu1]
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gir1.2-webkit2-4.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
gjs/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
google-chrome-stable/stable 121.0.6167.85-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 118.0.5993.88-1]
irqbalance/jammy-updates 1.8.0-1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.8.0-1build1]
libapparmor1/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2]
libapt-pkg6.0/jammy-updates 2.4.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.10]
libbinutils/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libcryptsetup12/jammy-updates 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1]
libctf-nobfd0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libctf0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.38-4ubuntu2.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.38-4ubuntu2.4]
libevdocument3-4/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
libevview3-3/jammy-updates 42.3-0ubuntu3.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.3-0ubuntu3]
libfprint-2-2/jammy-updates 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.06 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.04]
libgjs0g/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
libgnutls30/jammy-updates,jammy-security 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.3]
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libmm-glib0/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
libnetplan0/jammy-updates 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.3]
libnss-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libpam-modules-bin/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-modules/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-runtime/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 all [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libpam-systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libpam0g/jammy-updates,jammy-security 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3]
libsgutils2-2/jammy-updates 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.46-1build1]
libssh-4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libssh-gcrypt-4/jammy-updates,jammy-security 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.9.6-2ubuntu0.22.04.2]
libssl3/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
libssl3/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 i386 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
libsystemd0/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libudev1/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1]
libxnvctrl0/unknown 545.23.08-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.104.12-0ubuntu1]
linux-firmware/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.24 all [upgradable from: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.19]
linux-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04/jammy-updates,jammy-security 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8 amd64 [upgradable from: 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7]
linux-libc-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-92.102 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.0-91.101]
modemmanager/jammy-updates 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.20.0-1~ubuntu22.04.2]
netplan.io/jammy-updates 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.105-0ubuntu2~22.04.3]
nvidia-kernel-common-535/unknown 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.129.03-0ubuntu1]
nvidia-settings/unknown 545.23.08-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 535.104.12-0ubuntu1]
openssl/jammy-updates 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.13 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.12]
openvpn/jammy-updates 2.5.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.5.5-1ubuntu3.1]
python3-distro-info/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1.1ubuntu0.2 all [upgradable from: 1.1ubuntu0.1]
python3-paramiko/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2.9.3-0ubuntu1.2 all [upgradable from: 2.9.3-0ubuntu1]
python3-software-properties/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
python3-update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
software-properties-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
software-properties-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 0.99.22.9 all [upgradable from: 0.99.22.7]
systemd-hwe-hwdb/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 249.11.5 all [upgradable from: 249.11.3]
systemd-oomd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd-sysv/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd-timesyncd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
systemd/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
transmission-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 all [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
transmission-gtk/jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
tzdata/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04 all [upgradable from: 2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/jammy-updates 30~22.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 29.4~22.04]
ubuntu-drivers-common/jammy-updates 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.6 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.4]
udev/jammy-updates 249.11-0ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 249.11-0ubuntu3.10]
update-manager-core/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
update-manager/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.18 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.10]
xserver-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,jammy-security,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 all [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xephyr/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xorg-core/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xserver-xorg-legacy/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5]
xwayland/jammy-updates,jammy-security 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.9]
```

Also, I would like to know why `nvidia-kernel-common-535 | 535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 | jammy-security/restricted  | amd64, arm64` even is the correct package for updating Ubuntu 22.04 even though my error message only pops out `nvidia-kernel-common-535`? How did you know? Thank you very much!

Comment: The correct package is `nvidia-kernel-common-535 | 535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 | jammy-security/restricted  | amd64, arm64` for an updated Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, yet your paste shows an outdated `535.129.03-0ubuntu1` which would imply you haven't run `sudo apt update` OR you had warnings/errors you missed (did you read & check the output) or missing lines! (*missing lines can be harder to pick; so just check your actual sources.list file*). I'd likely explore `apt-cache policy nvidia-kernel-common-535` and check that (or all of `sudo apt update`) for clues..

Comment: I would try `sudo apt full-upgrade` and see if the packages you've not yet installed install that way (*there are cases; esp. when you add additional sources like you have with /var/cuda | developer.nvidia and/or local changes I'm not familiar with*)... The '***' besides an 3rd party source is why; have you any package holds?  (`apt-mark showhold`) that are preventing upgrade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 12):

I finally found my problem. My installation (or upgrade) is killed and pops out the error like

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.154.05-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Thus, I visit this post [dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062171/dpkg-deb-error-paste-subprocess-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe) and run

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.154.05-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
reboot
```

and then my `nvidia-smi` is recovered.

This is the first time I ask question on stackexchange and I apologize for not being familiar with the policy here. I appreciate all of your kind suggestions.

Comment: No need to apologize for *not being familiar* with the site... We're all *newbies* at some stage...   Well done !! for solving it    (*and sharing your answers so others can benefit from your learnt knowledge!*)